# Move multiple items in a list

Tags: c#

I have a list class that implements `IEnumerable<T>`.
Type T is a complex class with a string member as unique identifier. But it's enough to take just *int* as element type for explanations.

I want to move multiple items one step to left.
Example:
Original list: ***0***, 1, 2, **3**, **4**, 5
Now all bold items (0,3,4) should be moved to left (as far as possible).
Result list: ***0***, 1, **3**, **4**, 2, 5

Is there a good algorithm to do that? Maybe just with LINQ.

Edit: Answers for a `List<T>` list are welcome. My class has similar methods. (Thanks for hint by TylerOhlsen.)
Edit2: One selected item should not pass another selected item.

Comment: That's not really "as far as possible", do you mean to just move left one position?

Comment: @lc. One step to the left, as far as possible (e.g. `0` can't move)

Comment: @lc. Element *0* is not moved left. That is what I meant to be "as far as possible". And in case item *1* would also be marked to be moved (beside item *0*) then this move would be also ignored.

Comment: This one looks like could help...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431971/move-item-up-in-ienumerable

Comment: @Rawling wouldn't that yield a result like this: 0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5?

thersch do you want the list to look like this 0, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5 or 0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5 (the one you provided). In the latter one why doesn't the 1 move?

Comment: @ThomasLindvall He wants the bolded items (0, 3, 4) in the list to be moved one left, if possible.

Comment: You say it implements IEnumerable of T, but you also say it's a list.  Can you have it implement IList of T instead so that we can take advantage of IndexOf, RemoveAt, and Insert?

Comment: @ThomasLindvall I do not want to move bold items to start of list. I want only move **1 step** left. So if I try to move left items 0,1,3,4 the items 0 and 1 should be ignored because they are already on the most left side and items 3 and 4 should really be moved. So the result is 0,1,3,4,2,5.

Comment: @TylerOhlsen Our list has almost all methods that IList<T> has. (It is older code before generics come to .NET.) So answers for IList<T> would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't come up with a good way to use Linq, but here's a simple looping algorithm.  If you can come up with a Sort function, that would be better.  Or you could look at the Linq [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22SYSTEM.LINQ.ENUMERABLE.ZIP%60%603%22%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) method.

```
IList<int> myList = new List<int>(new[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
IList<int> moveLeftList = new List<int>(new[] {0, 1, 3, 4});

//Go through the original list in order and remove
// all items from the move left list until you reach
// the first item that is not going to be moved left.
//Items removed are already as far left as they can be
// so they do not need to be moved left and can therefore
// be safely removed from the list to be moved.
foreach (int item in myList)
{
    int index = moveLeftList.IndexOf(item);

    if (index >= 0)
        moveLeftList.RemoveAt(index);
    else
        break;
}

foreach (int item in moveLeftList)
{
    int index = myList.IndexOf(item);

    //Dont move left if it is the first item in the list or it is not in the list
    if (index <= 0)
        continue;

    //Swap with this item with the one to its left
    myList.RemoveAt(index);
    myList.Insert(index-1, item);
}
```

Comment: If your `moveLeftList` includes both `0` and `1`, does this swap them?

Comment: @TylerOhlsen One selected item should not pass another selected item.

Comment: Edited to now handle that special case since that only occurs for the first and subsequent items in the list.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like it works:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MoveSelectedLeft<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    IEnumerable<int> indicesToMove /* must be in order! */)
{
    using (var itm = indicesToMove.GetEnumerator())
    {
        bool hasNextToMove = itm.MoveNext();
        int nextToMove = hasNextToMove ? itm.Current : -1;

        bool canMoveYet = false;
        T held = default(T);
        int currentIndex = 0;

        foreach (T t in source)
        {
            if (hasNextToMove && nextToMove == currentIndex)
            {
                hasNextToMove = itm.MoveNext();
                nextToMove = hasNextToMove ? itm.Current : -1;
                yield return t;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!canMoveYet)
                {
                    canMoveYet = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return held;
                }
                held = t;
            }

            currentIndex++;
        }

        if (canMoveYet)
            yield return held;
    }
}
```

called as

```
foreach (int i in new[] { 0,1,2,3,4,5 }.MoveSelectedLeft(new[] { 0,3,4 }))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a description of an algorithm.  store the element directly to leftof your group of elements(in this case a `2`) in a `temp variable.

starting at the leftmost element, move the elements to the left 1 by 1.

place the `temp` variable to the right of where the group now is.

If you're using a linked list, it can be better.  you just remove the `2` from where it is, and insert it to the right of the group.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "Sort" function for this and provide a custom comparer.

Take a look at [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx).