# Move an array element from one array position to another

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to move an element of an array. For example, given the following:

```
var array = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
```

How can I write a function to move the element `'d'` to the left of `'b'` ?

Or `'a'` to the right of `'c'`?

After moving the elements, the indexes of the rest of the elements should be updated. The resulting array would be:

```
array = ['a', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'e']
```

This seems like it should be pretty simple, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: using ES6 `const changeValuePosition = (arr, init, target) => {[arr[init],arr[target]] = [arr[target],arr[init]]; return arr}`

Comment: That just swaps the elements at `init` and `target`.

Comment: @user4945014 It's not just swapping. If a swap occurs, the OP would get array = ['a', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'e'], which would mean 'c' and 'b' would be in the wrong order. An insert and shift as he's looking for will keep 'b' and 'c' in the same order.

Answer (score 887, accepted):

If you'd like a version on npm, [array-move](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-move) is the closest to this answer, although it's not the same implementation. See its usage section for more details. The previous version of this answer (that modified Array.prototype.move) can be found on npm at [array.prototype.move](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array.prototype.move).

---

I had fairly good success with this function:

```js
function array_move(arr, old_index, new_index) {
    if (new_index >= arr.length) {
        var k = new_index - arr.length + 1;
        while (k--) {
            arr.push(undefined);
        }
    }
    arr.splice(new_index, 0, arr.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
    return arr; // for testing
};

// returns [2, 1, 3]
console.log(array_move([1, 2, 3], 0, 1));
```

Note that the last `return` is simply for testing purposes: [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) performs operations on the array in-place, so a return is not necessary. By extension, this `move` is an in-place operation. If you want to avoid that and return a copy, use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Stepping through the code:

1. If `new_index` is greater than the length of the array, we want (I presume) to pad the array properly with new `undefined`s. This little snippet handles this by pushing `undefined` on the array until we have the proper length.
2. Then, in `arr.splice(old_index, 1)[0]`, we splice out the old element. `splice` returns the element that was spliced out, but it's in an array. In our above example, this was `[1]`. So we take the first index of that array to get the raw `1` there.
3. Then we use `splice` to insert this element in the new_index's place. Since we padded the array above if `new_index > arr.length`, it will probably appear in the right place, unless they've done something strange like pass in a negative number.

A fancier version to account for negative indices:

```js
function array_move(arr, old_index, new_index) {
    while (old_index < 0) {
        old_index += arr.length;
    }
    while (new_index < 0) {
        new_index += arr.length;
    }
    if (new_index >= arr.length) {
        var k = new_index - arr.length + 1;
        while (k--) {
            arr.push(undefined);
        }
    }
    arr.splice(new_index, 0, arr.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
    return arr; // for testing purposes
};
    
// returns [1, 3, 2]
console.log(array_move([1, 2, 3], -1, -2));
```

Which should account for things like `array_move([1, 2, 3], -1, -2)` properly (move the last element to the second to last place). Result for that should be `[1, 3, 2]`.

Either way, in your original question, you would do `array_move(arr, 0, 2)` for `a` after `c`. For `d` before `b`, you would do `array_move(arr, 3, 1)`.

Comment: This works perfectly! And your explanation is very clear. Thanks for taking the time to write this up.

Comment: You shouldn't manipulate Object and Array prototypes, it causes problems when iterating elements.

Comment: @burakemre: I think that conclusion is not so clearly reached. Most good JS programmers (and most popular libraries) will use a `.hasOwnProperty` check when iterating with things like for..in, especially with libraries like Prototype and MooTools which modify prototypes. Anyway, I didn't feel it was a particularly important issue in a relatively limited example like this, and there is a nice split in the community over whether or not prototype modification is a good idea. Normally, iteration problems are the least concern, though.

Comment: There is no need for the loop in step 1, you can simply use `this[new_index] = undefined;` within the `if` block. As Javascript arrays are sparse this will extend the array size to include the new_index for the `.splice` to work but without needing to create any intervening elements.

Comment: @Michael: Good point - but doing `this[new_index] = undefined` will actually put an `undefined` in the array slot *before* the correct index. (E.g., `[1,2,3].move(0,10)` will have `1` in slot 10 and `undefined` in slot 9.) Rather, if sparseness is OK, we could do `this[new_index] = this.splice(old_index, 1)[0]` without the other splice call (make it an if/else instead).

Comment: I've added Reid's code (the "fancier" version) as an npm package at https://www.npmjs.com/package/array.prototype.move.

I've credited Reid appropriately there, I hope.  Please let me know if not.

Comment: PLEASE PLEASE don't add this to the prototype. When the TC39 wants to add it natively to JavaScript they will have to use a different, awkward name because of people doing this.

Comment: I've updated the post so that it doesn't modify the array prototype. Looking back, I recognize that modifying the prototype was on shaky ground at best in 2011, and now that we're in 2018, it's high time I changed the post.

Comment: So it seems to work with just this:
``function array_move(arr: any[], oldIndex: number, newIndex: number) {
    arr.splice(newIndex, 0, arr.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0]);
    return arr;
  }``
Why are we pushing falsy values?

Comment: `Array.splice()` already handles negative numbers. There's no need for the second section of code.

Comment: After some testing i get some null item added to the original array

Comment: Actually I see a problem here: if I call `array_move([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 1)`, then an item with index `3` is moved at the position before an item with index `1`, it works fine. However by calling `array_move([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 1, 3)` I expect the same behavior - that an item with index `1` is moved BEFORE an item with index `3` - so the expected result would be `[0, 2, 1, 3, 4]`, which is not. Correct code should imo be `arr.splice(new_index > old_index ? new_index - 1 : new_index, 0, arr.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);`

Comment: Don't use this solution, there is much better one without creating new arrays from @Merc.

Answer (score 544):

I like this method as it's concise and it just works.

```
function arraymove(arr, fromIndex, toIndex) {
    var element = arr[fromIndex];
    arr.splice(fromIndex, 1);
    arr.splice(toIndex, 0, element);
}
```

Note: always remember to check your array bounds.

The following snippet prints a few tests in console to show all combinations of `fromIndex` and `toIndex` *(0..n, 0..n)* work.

[Run Snippet in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7gpwedct/1/)

Comment: Since Array.splice returns the removed value(s) in a new Array, you can write it as a one liner... arr.splice(index + 1, 0, arr.splice(index, 1)[0]);

Comment: Personally I prefer the 3 line code. It's easier to understand: Get a copy of the element; remove it from the array; insert it in a new position. The one liner is shorter but not so clear for other people to understand...

Comment: Short and simple code. But it's 2019!!, Create a clone of the array and return it instead of mutating the array. This will make your function "arraymove" comply to functional programming standards

Comment: Functional programming is great in many situations but not everything needs to, nor has to comply to functional programming standards. If you're a pure functions warrior this can still be useful locally. It depends by how fine grain your functional methods are.

Comment: It's 2020. Please don't mutate array inside a function.

Comment: Care explaining why not?

Comment: I would have never imagine that for some people, after 2019, mutating an array in place would have become out of fashion. Perfectly legit answer, +1.

Comment: It's 2021. There are still cases where copying is totally inappropriate for memory/performance reasons. Pure functions should be the default, but it shouldn't be dogma.

Comment: 2022 here - recently had to work with massive datasets in javascript and I can tell you now, cloning to make a simple change or using array functions is not a good idea at all. I hate this mentality of "having" to make everything immutable. Javascript wasn't designed to be immutable, if it was, it'd be efficient to program in this manner.

Comment: @SamwellTarly 1979-2022 here: one size does not fit all; horses for courses -- OP did not specify the need for a pure function, or that he was working with a dataset whose size would make it practical.

Comment: The key is in understanding how Array. splice work.
The first ```slice``` removed the value we want to move and then the second ```slice``` pushed that value we want to move to the index we want to move it. That operation will move other values by the right, further right.

Comment: Everybody talking about not mutating the array and nobody noticed that if `toIndex` is greater than `fromIndex` it needs to be decremented??

Comment: @Ricardo decrement what? Have you tried the snippet? It tests all permutations of couples ([0..5], [0..5]). If you look at the console you'll see all correct results.

Answer (score 333):

Here's a one liner I found on JSPerf....

```
Array.prototype.move = function(from, to) {
    this.splice(to, 0, this.splice(from, 1)[0]);
};
```

which is awesome to read, but if you want performance (in small data sets) try...

```
 Array.prototype.move2 = function(pos1, pos2) {
    // local variables
    var i, tmp;
    // cast input parameters to integers
    pos1 = parseInt(pos1, 10);
    pos2 = parseInt(pos2, 10);
    // if positions are different and inside array
    if (pos1 !== pos2 && 0 <= pos1 && pos1 <= this.length && 0 <= pos2 && pos2 <= this.length) {
      // save element from position 1
      tmp = this[pos1];
      // move element down and shift other elements up
      if (pos1 < pos2) {
        for (i = pos1; i < pos2; i++) {
          this[i] = this[i + 1];
        }
      }
      // move element up and shift other elements down
      else {
        for (i = pos1; i > pos2; i--) {
          this[i] = this[i - 1];
        }
      }
      // put element from position 1 to destination
      this[pos2] = tmp;
    }
  }
```

I can't take any credit, it should all go to [Richard Scarrott](https://www.redips.net/javascript/array-move/). It beats the splice based method for smaller data sets in this [performance test](https://jsbench.me/1qkxqhvxvr). It is however significantly slower on larger data sets [as Darwayne points out](https://web.archive.org/web/20181026015734/https://jsperf.com/array-prototype-move/8).

Comment: This move2 method is nice, as it allows for moving the an array element either up or down the array.  I ran into problems, with some of the other solutions when moving array elements to the right.

Comment: Your more performant solution is slower on large datasets. http://jsperf.com/array-prototype-move/8

Comment: This seems like a really silly tradeof. Performance on small data sets is a negligible gain, but loss on large data sets is a significant loss. Your net exchange is negative.

Comment: The one-liner is nice, but does not handle moving elements beyond the end of the array.

Comment: @Reid That wasn't a requirement. IMO it is okay to assume that the length of the array doesn't get modified.

Comment: It should go to note array.prototype.move is no longer supported.

Comment: One line solution need to handle two situations:
`from >= to ? this.splice(to, 0, this.splice(from, 1)[0]) : this.splice(to - 1, 0, this.splice(from, 1)[0]);`

Comment: Please never modify builtin prototypes, ever. http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/

Comment: do not add things in the prototype, guys

Comment: I know that this is old, but I cant move the element at first position to the last position with the 1liner - Any idea?

Comment: great solution, and I believe it is a right use case for adding it as a prototype. Big like!

Comment: @Kyeotic. Not if you know before hand you deal only with smaller data sets, but lots of them.

Answer (score 47):

> The splice() method adds/removes items to/from an array, and returns the **removed** item(s).
>
> Note: This method changes the original array. /w3schools/

```
Array.prototype.move = function(from,to){
  this.splice(to,0,this.splice(from,1)[0]);
  return this;
};

var arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
arr.move(3,1);//["a", "d", "b", "c", "e"]


var arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
arr.move(0,2);//["b", "c", "a", "d", "e"]
```

as the function is [chainable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) this works too:

```
alert(arr.move(0,2).join(','));
```

[demo here](http://jsbin.com/ohibob/1/edit)

Comment: See other comments about this: it's a bad idea to modify built-in prototypes like Array and Object. You will break things.

Answer (score 38):

My 2c. Easy to read, it works, it's fast, it doesn't create new arrays.

```
function move(array, from, to) {
  if( to === from ) return array;

  var target = array[from];                         
  var increment = to < from ? -1 : 1;

  for(var k = from; k != to; k += increment){
    array[k] = array[k + increment];
  }
  array[to] = target;
  return array;
}
```

Comment: At first string of function you should return ``array``, as it done at the end.

Comment: True how did i miss that? Fixed!

Comment: I like your simple and flexible solution the most. Thx!

Comment: TypeScript coders, scroll down to find my answer which is based upon this excellent answer by @Merc, that I remixed with added types.

Answer (score 26):

Here is my **one liner ES6 solution** with an optional parameter `on`.

```
if (typeof Array.prototype.move === "undefined") {
  Array.prototype.move = function(from, to, on = 1) {
    this.splice(to, 0, ...this.splice(from, on))
  }
}
```

*Adaptation of the first solution proposed by `digiguru`*

The parameter `on` is the number of element starting from `from` you want to move.

Here is a chainable variation of this:

```
if (typeof Array.prototype.move === "undefined") {
  Array.prototype.move = function(from, to, on = 1) {
    return this.splice(to, 0, ...this.splice(from, on)), this
  }
}

[3, 4, 5, 1, 2].move(3, 0, 2) // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If you'd like to avoid prototype pollution, here's a stand-alone function:

```
function move(array, from, to, on = 1) {
  return array.splice(to, 0, ...array.splice(from, on)), array
}

move([3, 4, 5, 1, 2], 3, 0, 2) // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

And finally, here's a pure function that doesn't mutate the original array:

```
function moved(array, from, to, on = 1) {
  return array = array.slice(), array.splice(to, 0, ...array.splice(from, on)), array
}
```

This should cover basically every variation seen in every other answer.

Comment: The solution is fine. However, when you expand a prototype you shouldn't use arrow function because in this case 'this' is not an array instance but for example Window object.

Comment: This is my favorite answer - modern, concise and simple. I added a chainable variation, to be more consistent with the standard Array methods. Some folks are going to take issue with prototype pollution, so I added a stand-alone function as well. Finally, some use-cases require a pure function, as opposed to in-place manipulation, so I added that as well.

Comment: I couldn't understand the last pure function. Is that statement comma separated? How does it work?

Comment: @batbrain9392 - Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10284536/1914985

Answer (score 21):

Got this idea from @Reid of pushing something in the place of the item that is supposed to be moved to keep the array size constant. That does simplify calculations. Also, pushing an empty object has the added benefits of being able to search for it uniquely later on. This works because two objects are not equal until they are referring to the same object.

```
({}) == ({}); // false
```

So here's the function which takes in the source array, and the source, destination indexes. You could add it to the Array.prototype if needed.

```
function moveObjectAtIndex(array, sourceIndex, destIndex) {
    var placeholder = {};
    // remove the object from its initial position and
    // plant the placeholder object in its place to
    // keep the array length constant
    var objectToMove = array.splice(sourceIndex, 1, placeholder)[0];
    // place the object in the desired position
    array.splice(destIndex, 0, objectToMove);
    // take out the temporary object
    array.splice(array.indexOf(placeholder), 1);
}
```

Comment: This looks promising...and I didn't know that about javascript js comparisons. Thanks!

Comment: Does't works for case ``sourceIndex = 0``, ``destIndex = 1``

Comment: `destIndex` is meant to be the index before the source element is moved in the array.

Comment: This is the best answer so far. Other answers failed a couple of unit tests in my suite (moving object forward)

Answer (score 16):

This is based on @Reid's solution. Except:

- I'm not changing the `Array` prototype.
- Moving an item out of bounds to the right does not create `undefined` items, it just moves the item to the right-most position.

Function:

```
function move(array, oldIndex, newIndex) {
    if (newIndex >= array.length) {
        newIndex = array.length - 1;
    }
    array.splice(newIndex, 0, array.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0]);
    return array;
}
```

Unit tests:

```
describe('ArrayHelper', function () {
    it('Move right', function () {
        let array = [1, 2, 3];
        arrayHelper.move(array, 0, 1);
        assert.equal(array[0], 2);
        assert.equal(array[1], 1);
        assert.equal(array[2], 3);
    })
    it('Move left', function () {
        let array = [1, 2, 3];
        arrayHelper.move(array, 1, 0);
        assert.equal(array[0], 2);
        assert.equal(array[1], 1);
        assert.equal(array[2], 3);
    });
    it('Move out of bounds to the left', function () {
        let array = [1, 2, 3];
        arrayHelper.move(array, 1, -2);
        assert.equal(array[0], 2);
        assert.equal(array[1], 1);
        assert.equal(array[2], 3);
    });
    it('Move out of bounds to the right', function () {
        let array = [1, 2, 3];
        arrayHelper.move(array, 1, 4);
        assert.equal(array[0], 1);
        assert.equal(array[1], 3);
        assert.equal(array[2], 2);
    });
});
```

Comment: this is wrong,  if you insert a post position, the index will change since you have remove the item

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to remove an item from an array without leaving a null element (which occured when using splice(indexToRemove). I used your method to move the item I wanted to remove to the end of the array, and then used the pop() method to remove.

Comment: liked "move the item to the right-most position" feature, useful for my case. thx

Answer (score 10):

You can implement some basic calculus and create a universal function for moving array elements from one position to the other.

For JavaScript it looks like this:

```
function magicFunction (targetArray, indexFrom, indexTo) { 

    targetElement = targetArray[indexFrom]; 
    magicIncrement = (indexTo - indexFrom) / Math.abs (indexTo - indexFrom); 

    for (Element = indexFrom; Element != indexTo; Element += magicIncrement){ 
        targetArray[Element] = targetArray[Element + magicIncrement]; 
    } 

    targetArray[indexTo] = targetElement; 

}
```

Check out "moving array elements" at "Gloommatter" for detailed explanation.

https://web.archive.org/web/20121105042534/http://www.gloommatter.com:80/DDesign/programming/moving-any-array-elements-universal-function.html

Comment: This ought to be the correct answer, as it does not allocate any new arrays. Thanks!

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Solution is great!  I loved this solution as it does not use splice function but does not work for negative indexes and also does not check for array outbound.

Answer (score 9):

I've implemented an immutable `ECMAScript 6` solution based off of `@Merc`'s answer over here:

```
const moveItemInArrayFromIndexToIndex = (array, fromIndex, toIndex) => {
  if (fromIndex === toIndex) return array;

  const newArray = [...array];

  const target = newArray[fromIndex];
  const inc = toIndex < fromIndex ? -1 : 1;

  for (let i = fromIndex; i !== toIndex; i += inc) {
    newArray[i] = newArray[i + inc];
  }

  newArray[toIndex] = target;

  return newArray;
};
```

The variable names can be shortened, just used long ones so that the code can explain itself.

Comment: definitely a better answer, mutations creates side effects

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just return `array` immediately if  `fromIndex === toIndex`, and only create the `newArray` if it's not the case? Immutability doesn't mean that one fresh copy must be created per function call even when there's no change. Just asking b/c the motive for the increased length of this function (relative to splice based one-liners) is performance, and `fromIndex` may well often equal `toIndex`, depending on the usage.

Answer (score 7):

One approach would be to use `splice()` to remove the item from the array and then by using `splice()` method again, insert the removed item into the *target index*.

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

const newArray = moveItem(array, 3, 1) // move element from index 3 to index 1

function moveItem(arr, fromIndex, toIndex){
  let itemRemoved = arr.splice(fromIndex, 1) // assign the removed item as an array
  arr.splice(toIndex, 0, itemRemoved[0]) // insert itemRemoved into the target index
  return arr
}

console.log(newArray)
```

You can find a short explanation of **splice()** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index/70605199#70605199)

Answer (score 7):

In 2022, this typescript utility will work along with a unit test.

```ts
export const arrayMove = <T>(arr: T[], fromIndex: number, toIndex: number) => {
  const newArr = [...arr];
  newArr.splice(toIndex, 0, newArr.splice(fromIndex, 1)[0]);
  return newArr;
};
```

```js
const testArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];

describe('arrayMove', () => {
  it('should move array item to toIndex', () => {
    expect(arrayMove(testArray, 2, 0)).toEqual(['3', '1', '2', '4']);
    expect(arrayMove(testArray, 3, 1)).toEqual(['1', '4', '2', '3']);
    expect(arrayMove(testArray, 1, 2)).toEqual(['1', '3', '2', '4']);
    expect(arrayMove(testArray, 0, 2)).toEqual(['2', '3', '1', '4']);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

One approach would be to create a new array with the pieces in the order you want, using the slice method.

Example

```
var arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
var arr2 = arr.slice(0,1).concat( ['d'] ).concat( arr.slice(2,4) ).concat( arr.slice(4) );
```

- arr.slice(0,1) gives you ['a']
- arr.slice(2,4) gives you ['b', 'c']
- arr.slice(4) gives you ['e']

Comment: You do realize that your `arr2` ends up being a string due to the concatenation operations, right? :)  It ends up being `"adc,de"`.

Answer (score 6):

Another pure JS variant using ES6 array spread operator with no mutation

```js
const reorder = (array, sourceIndex, destinationIndex) => {
 const smallerIndex = Math.min(sourceIndex, destinationIndex);
 const largerIndex = Math.max(sourceIndex, destinationIndex);

 return [
  ...array.slice(0, smallerIndex),
  ...(sourceIndex < destinationIndex
   ? array.slice(smallerIndex + 1, largerIndex + 1)
   : []),
  array[sourceIndex],
  ...(sourceIndex > destinationIndex
   ? array.slice(smallerIndex, largerIndex)
   : []),
  ...array.slice(largerIndex + 1),
 ];
}

// returns ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'f']
console.log(reorder(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], 1, 4))
```

Comment: I personally loved this and with the next search will run across this again ... so adding my own personalized implementation ...

const swapIndex = (array, from, to) => (
  from < to 
    ? [...array.slice(0, from), ...array.slice(from + 1, to + 1), array[from], ...array.slice(to + 1)] 
    : [...array.slice(0, to), array[from], ...array.slice(to, from), ...array.slice(from + 1)]
);

Comment: This answer should be higher thanks to the purity.

Comment: This answer is amazing. Non-mutative, and it does boundary checks elegantly. However, there's a bug. If you define a sourceIndex that does not exist in the array, you end up with an array 1 size larger than the original that includes an undefined value. Eg [1,2,3,4,5] becomes [undefined,1,2,3,4,5]

Answer (score 5):

The `splice` method of `Array` might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Just keep in mind it might be relatively expensive since it has to actively re-index the array.

Comment: Yep, but as soon as I perform the splice, the array indices are updated, which makes it difficult for me to figure out where to place the element that I just removed. Especially since I need the function to be able to handle moves in both directions.

Comment: @Mark: don't splice the string and save it into the same variable, make a new string and splice that. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

I needed an immutable move method (one that didn't change the original array), so I adapted @Reid's accepted answer to simply use Object.assign to create a copy of the array before doing the splice.

```
Array.prototype.immutableMove = function (old_index, new_index) {
  var copy = Object.assign([], this);
  if (new_index >= copy.length) {
      var k = new_index - copy.length;
      while ((k--) + 1) {
          copy.push(undefined);
      }
  }
  copy.splice(new_index, 0, copy.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
  return copy;
};
```

Here is a [jsfiddle showing it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/javidjamae/76ws6c01/2/).

Comment: It's always good to see ppl taking mutations into considerations.

Answer (score 5):

## TypeScript Version

Copied from @Merc's answer.  I like that one best because it is not creating new arrays and modifies the array in place.  All I did was update to ES6 and add the types.

```
export function moveItemInArray<T>(workArray: T[], fromIndex: number, toIndex: number): T[] {
    if (toIndex === fromIndex) {
        return workArray;
    }
    const target = workArray[fromIndex];
    const increment = toIndex < fromIndex ? -1 : 1;

    for (let k = fromIndex; k !== toIndex; k += increment) {
        workArray[k] = workArray[k + increment];
    }
    workArray[toIndex] = target;
    return workArray;
}
```

Comment: Love this one -- thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
    Array.prototype.moveUp = function (value, by) {
        var index = this.indexOf(value),
            newPos = index - (by || 1);

        if (index === -1)
            throw new Error("Element not found in array");

        if (newPos < 0)
            newPos = 0;

        this.splice(index, 1);
        this.splice(newPos, 0, value);
    };

    Array.prototype.moveDown = function (value, by) {
        var index = this.indexOf(value),
            newPos = index + (by || 1);

        if (index === -1)
            throw new Error("Element not found in array");

        if (newPos >= this.length)
            newPos = this.length;

        this.splice(index, 1);
        this.splice(newPos, 0, value);
    };



    var arr = ['banana', 'curyWurst', 'pc', 'remembaHaruMembaru'];

    alert('withiout changes= '+arr[0]+' ||| '+arr[1]+' ||| '+arr[2]+' ||| '+arr[3]);
    arr.moveDown(arr[2]);


    alert('third word moved down= '+arr[0] + ' ||| ' + arr[1] + ' ||| ' + arr[2] + ' ||| ' + arr[3]);
    arr.moveUp(arr[2]);
    alert('third word moved up= '+arr[0] + ' ||| ' + arr[1] + ' ||| ' + arr[2] + ' ||| ' + arr[3]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/JaiAaO7FQcdPGPY6G337?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it in an immutable way. It handles negative numbers as well as an added bonus. This is reduces number of possible bugs at the cost of performance compared to editing the original array.

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
const moveElement = (array, from, to) => {
  const copy = [...array];
  const valueToMove = copy.splice(from, 1)[0];
  copy.splice(to, 0, valueToMove);
  return copy;
};

console.log(moveElement(numbers, 0, 2))
// > [2, 3, 1]
console.log(moveElement(numbers, -1, -3))
// > [3, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

## Find and move an element from "n"th position to 0th position.

Eg: Find and move 'd' to 0th position:

```
let arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
arr = [...arr.filter(item => item === 'd'), ...arr.filter(item => item !== 'd')];
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up combining two of these to work a little better when moving both small and large distances. I get fairly consistent results, but this could probably be tweaked a little bit by someone smarter than me to work differently for different sizes, etc.

Using some of the other methods when moving objects small distances was significantly faster (x10) than using splice.  This might change depending on the array lengths though, but it is true for large arrays.

```
function ArrayMove(array, from, to) {
    if ( Math.abs(from - to) > 60) {
        array.splice(to, 0, array.splice(from, 1)[0]);
    } else {
        // works better when we are not moving things very far
        var target = array[from];
        var inc = (to - from) / Math.abs(to - from);
        var current = from;
        for (; current != to; current += inc) {
            array[current] = array[current + inc];
        }
        array[to] = target;    
    }
}
```

https://web.archive.org/web/20181026015711/https://jsperf.com/arraymove-many-sizes

Answer (score 2):

It is stated in many places ([adding custom functions into Array.prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948358/adding-custom-functions-into-array-prototype)) playing with the Array prototype could be a bad idea, anyway I combined the best from various posts, I came with this, using modern Javascript:

```
    Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'immutableMove', {
        enumerable: false,
        value: function (old_index, new_index) {
            var copy = Object.assign([], this)
            if (new_index >= copy.length) {
                var k = new_index - copy.length;
                while ((k--) + 1) { copy.push(undefined); }
            }
            copy.splice(new_index, 0, copy.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
            return copy
        }
    });

    //how to use it
    myArray=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
    myArray=myArray.immutableMove(2, 4);
    console.log(myArray);
    //result: 0, 1, 3, 4, 2
```

Hope can be useful to anyone

Answer (score 2):

This version isn't ideal for all purposes, and not everyone likes comma expressions, but here's a one-liner that's a pure expression, creating a fresh copy:

```
const move = (from, to, ...a) => (a.splice(to, 0, ...a.splice(from, 1)), a)
```

A slightly performance-improved version returns the input array if no move is needed, it's still OK for immutable use, as the array won't change, and it's still a pure expression:

```
const move = (from, to, ...a) => 
    from === to 
    ? a 
    : (a.splice(to, 0, ...a.splice(from, 1)), a)
```

The invocation of either is

```
const shuffled = move(fromIndex, toIndex, ...list)
```

i.e. it relies on spreading to generate a fresh copy. Using a fixed arity 3 `move` would jeopardize either the single expression property, or the non-destructive nature, or the performance benefit of `splice`. Again, it's more of an example that meets some criteria than a suggestion for production use.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const move = (from, to, ...a) =>from === to ? a : (a.splice(to, 0, ...a.splice(from, 1)), a);
const moved = move(0, 2, ...['a', 'b', 'c']);
console.log(moved)
```

Answer (score 2):

I thought this was a swap problem but it's not. Here's my one-liner solution:

```
const move = (arr, from, to) => arr.map((item, i) => i === to ? arr[from] : (i >= Math.min(from, to) && i <= Math.max(from, to) ? arr[i + Math.sign(to - from)] : item));
```

Here's a small test:

```
let test = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
console.log(move(test, 0, 2)); // [ 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e' ]
console.log(move(test, 1, 3)); // [ 'a', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'e' ]
console.log(move(test, 2, 4)); // [ 'a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'c' ]
console.log(move(test, 2, 0)); // [ 'c', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'e' ]
console.log(move(test, 3, 1)); // [ 'a', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'e' ]
console.log(move(test, 4, 2)); // [ 'a', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'd' ]
console.log(move(test, 4, 0)); // [ 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
```

Comment: Well, the question was not about swapping items. The author asked for a solution for an insert strategy.

Comment: With regard to the question at hand, this is objectively the wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really simple method using splice

```js
Array.prototype.moveToStart = function(index) {
    this.splice(0, 0, this.splice(index, 1)[0]);
    return this;
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

I love immutable, functional one liners :) ...

```
const swapIndex = (array, from, to) => (
  from < to 
    ? [...array.slice(0, from), ...array.slice(from + 1, to + 1), array[from], ...array.slice(to + 1)] 
    : [...array.slice(0, to), array[from], ...array.slice(to, from), ...array.slice(from + 1)]
);
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: To the untrained eye, this is absolutely horrendously complicated. Why are people obsessed with one liners these days? It's not like you can't afford to use some whitespace...

Answer (score 1):

Object oriented, expressive, debuggable, without mutation, tested.

```
class Sorter {
    sortItem(array, fromIndex, toIndex) {
        const reduceItems = () => {
            const startingItems = array.slice(0, fromIndex);
            const endingItems = array.slice(fromIndex + 1);
            return startingItems.concat(endingItems);
        }
        const addMovingItem = (movingItem, reducedItems) => {
            const startingNewItems = reducedItems.slice(0, toIndex);
            const endingNewItems = reducedItems.slice(toIndex);
            const newItems = startingNewItems.concat([movingItem]).concat(endingNewItems);
            return newItems;
        }
        const movingItem = array[fromIndex];
        const reducedItems = reduceItems();
        const newItems = addMovingItem(movingItem, reducedItems);
        return newItems;
    }
}

const sorter = new Sorter();
export default sorter;
```

```
import sorter from 'src/common/Sorter';

test('sortItem first item forward', () => {
    const startingArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    const expectedArray = ['b', 'a', 'c', 'd'];
    expect(sorter.sortItem(startingArray, 0, 1)).toStrictEqual(expectedArray);
});
test('sortItem middle item forward', () => {
    const startingArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    const expectedArray = ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'];
    expect(sorter.sortItem(startingArray, 1, 2)).toStrictEqual(expectedArray);
});
test('sortItem middle item backward', () => {
    const startingArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    const expectedArray = ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'];
    expect(sorter.sortItem(startingArray, 2, 1)).toStrictEqual(expectedArray);
});
test('sortItem last item backward', () => {
    const startingArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    const expectedArray = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c'];
    expect(sorter.sortItem(startingArray, 3, 2)).toStrictEqual(expectedArray);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Array.move.js

### Summary

Moves elements within an array, returning an array containing the moved elements.

### Syntax

```
array.move(index, howMany, toIndex);
```

### Parameters

**index**: Index at which to move elements. If negative, **index** will start from the end.

**howMany**: Number of elements to move from **index**.

**toIndex**: Index of the array at which to place the moved elements. If negative, **toIndex** will start from the end.

### Usage

```
array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];

array.move(3, 2, 1); // returns ["d","e"]

array; // returns ["a", "d", "e", "b", "c", "f", "g"]
```

### Polyfill

```
Array.prototype.move || Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "move", {
    value: function (index, howMany, toIndex) {
        var
        array = this,
        index = parseInt(index) || 0,
        index = index < 0 ? array.length + index : index,
        toIndex = parseInt(toIndex) || 0,
        toIndex = toIndex < 0 ? array.length + toIndex : toIndex,
        toIndex = toIndex <= index ? toIndex : toIndex <= index + howMany ? index : toIndex - howMany,
        moved;

        array.splice.apply(array, [toIndex, 0].concat(moved = array.splice(index, howMany)));

        return moved;
    }
});
```

Comment: While the `.move` looks like it should work (I haven't tested it), you should note that it isn't part of any standard.  It is also good to warn folks that polyfill/monkeypatched functions can break some code that assumes everything enumerable is theirs.

Comment: a=["a", "b", "c"];a.move(0,1,1); // a = ["a", "b", "c"], should be ["b", "a", "c"]

Comment: This feature is obsolete and may not supported any more. Be careful See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/move

Answer (score 0):

I used the nice [answer of @Reid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5306832/2508405), but struggled with moving an element from the end of an array one step further - to the beginning (like in a **loop**).
E.g. ['a', 'b', 'c'] should become ['c', 'a', 'b'] by calling .move(2,3)

I achieved this by changing the case for new_index >= this.length.

```
Array.prototype.move = function (old_index, new_index) {
        console.log(old_index + " " + new_index);
        while (old_index < 0) {
            old_index += this.length;
        }
        while (new_index < 0) {
            new_index += this.length;
        }
        if (new_index >= this.length) {
            new_index = new_index % this.length;
        }
        this.splice(new_index, 0, this.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
        return this; // for testing purposes
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to [Reid's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306680/move-an-array-element-from-one-array-position-to-another#answer-5306832) (and because I cannot comment);
You can use modulo to make both negative indices and too large indices "roll over":

```js
function array_move(arr, old_index, new_index) {
  new_index =((new_index % arr.length) + arr.length) % arr.length;
  arr.splice(new_index, 0, arr.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
  return arr; // for testing
}

// returns [2, 1, 3]
console.log(array_move([1, 2, 3], 0, 1));
```

Comment: Yes - since negative indices are supported, it seems sensible to wrap too-large indices rather than inserting undefined values, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
let ar = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

function change( old_array, old_index , new_index ){

  return old_array.map(( item , index, array )=>{
    if( index === old_index ) return array[ new_index ];
    else if( index === new_index ) return array[ old_index ];
    else return item;
  });

}

let result = change( ar, 0, 1 );

console.log( result );
```

result:

```
["b", "a", "c", "d"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let oldi, newi, arr;
    
    if(newi !== oldi) {
      let el = this.arr.splice(oldi, 1);
      if(newi > oldi && newi === (this.arr.length + 2)) {
        this.arr.push("");
      }
      this.arr.splice(newi, 0, el);
      if(newi > oldi && newi === (this.arr.length + 2)) {
        this.arr.pop();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! There are 21 additional answers... so, please, don´t just place code. Explain the benefit of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ELEMS = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
/*
    Source item will remove and it will be placed just after destination
*/
function moveItemTo(sourceItem, destItem, elements) {
    var sourceIndex = elements.indexOf(sourceItem);
    var destIndex = elements.indexOf(destItem);
    if (sourceIndex >= -1 && destIndex > -1) {
        elements.splice(destIndex, 0, elements.splice(sourceIndex, 1)[0]);
    }
    return elements;
}
console.log('Init: ', ELEMS);
var result = moveItemTo('a', 'c', ELEMS);
console.log('BeforeAfter: ', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Immutable version without array copy:

```
const moveInArray = (arr, fromIndex, toIndex) => {
  if (toIndex === fromIndex || toIndex >= arr.length) return arr;

  const toMove = arr[fromIndex];
  const movedForward = fromIndex < toIndex;

  return arr.reduce((res, next, index) => {
    if (index === fromIndex) return res;
    if (index === toIndex) return res.concat(
      movedForward ? [next, toMove] : [toMove, next]
    );

    return res.concat(next);
  }, []);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is define a new property for Arrays

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'move', {
    value: function (old_index, new_index) {
        while (old_index < 0) {
            old_index += this.length;
        }
        while (new_index < 0) {
            new_index += this.length;
        }
        if (new_index >= this.length) {
            let k = new_index - this.length;
            while ((k--) + 1) {
                this.push(undefined);
            }
        }
        this.splice(new_index, 0, this.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
        return this;
    }
});

console.log([10, 20, 30, 40, 50].move(0, 1));  // [20, 10, 30, 40, 50]
console.log([10, 20, 30, 40, 50].move(0, 2));  // [20, 30, 10, 40, 50]
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will preserve the original array, and check for bounding errors.

```
const move = (from, to, arr) => {
    to = Math.max(to,0)
    from > to 
        ? [].concat(
            arr.slice(0,to), 
            arr[from], 
            arr.filter((x,i) => i != from).slice(to)) 
        : to > from
            ? [].concat(
                arr.slice(0, from), 
                arr.slice(from + 1, to + 1), 
                arr[from], 
                arr.slice(to + 1))
            : arr}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, because is an array of `string` we can use a ranking object to reorder the string array:

```
let rank =  { 'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 0.5, 'e': 4 };
arr.sort( (i, j) => rank[i] - rank[j] );
```

We can use this approach to write a `move` function that works on a string array:

```js
function stringArrayMove(arr, from, to)
{
  let rank = arr.reduce( (p, c, i) => ( p[c] = i, p ), ({ }) );
  // rank = { 'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3, 'e': 4 }
  rank[arr[from]] = to - 0.5;
  // rank = { 'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 1.5, 'e': 4 }
  arr.sort( (i, j) => rank[i] - rank[j] );
  // arr = [ 'a', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'e' ];
}

let arr = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ];
stringArrayMove(arr, 3, 1);
console.log( JSON.stringify(arr) );
```

If, however, the thing we wanted to sort is an array of object, we can introduce the ranking as a new property of each object, i.e.

```
let arr = [ { value: 'a', rank: 0 },
            { value: 'b', rank: 1 },
            { value: 'c', rank: 2 },
            { value: 'd', rank: 0.5 },
            { value: 'e', rank: 4 } ];
arr.sort( (i, j) => i['rank'] - j['rank'] );
```

We can use `Symbol` to hide the visibility of this property, i.e. it will not be shown in `JSON.stringify`. We can generalize this in an `objectArrayMove` function:

```js
function objectArrayMove(arr, from, to) {
  let rank = Symbol("rank");
  arr.forEach( (item, i) => item[rank] = i );
  arr[from][rank] = to - 0.5;
  arr.sort( (i, j) => i[rank] - j[rank]);
}
let arr = [ { value: 'a' }, { value: 'b' }, { value: 'c' }, { value: 'd' }, { value: 'e' } ];
console.log( 'array before move: ', JSON.stringify( arr ) );
// array before move:  [{"value":"a"},{"value":"b"},{"value":"c"},{"value":"d"},{"value":"e"}]
objectArrayMove(arr, 3, 1);
console.log( 'array after move: ', JSON.stringify( arr ) );
// array after move:  [{"value":"a"},{"value":"d"},{"value":"b"},{"value":"c"},{"value":"e"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the object is nested:

```
  let array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
  let existingElement = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array[3]));
  array.splice(1, 0, existingElement);
  array.splice(4, 1);
  console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue using `immutability-helper` library.

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

const move = (arr: any[], from: number, to: number) => update(arr, {
  $splice: [
    [from, 1],
    [to, 0, arr[from] as string],
  ],
});

const testArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
console.log(move(testArray, 1, 3)); // [ 'c', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ]
console.log(move(testArray, 4, 0)); // [ 'e', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

As with everything, the full use is what matters.

There are perfectly fine answers here for a single move, and for both small and large data sets.
If you're doing thousands of moves though, I'd suggest looking at states and less-frequent intensive operations. Something like:

- Change your data set, keep an order "status" against each item.
- Apply thousands of updates.
- Perform a single sort on that order attribute.

```
 ["a", "b", "c"]
```

would change to

```
[
   {val: 'a', order: 0},
   {val: 'b', order: 1},
   {val: 'c', order: 2},

]
```

Then, apply thousands of updates.

Finally, you sort by the "order" variable.
And perhaps renumber things too.

I haven't tested the performance of this, but can imagine at a certain level of usage it'd be better than trying to rebuild arrays every 1000s of times.

Answer (score 0):

We can move array element from one position to another position in many ways. Here I try to solve this in 3 ways in immutably.

### Move array element using `splice` where time complexity is Quadratic Time - O(n^2)

```js
function arrayMove(arr, oldIndex, newIndex) {
  const copiedArr = [...arr];
  const length = copiedArr.length;
  
  if (oldIndex !== newIndex && length > oldIndex && length > newIndex) {
    copiedArr.splice(newIndex, 0, copiedArr.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0]);
  }
  
  return copiedArr;
}

arrayMove([1,2,3,4], 0, 3) // [2,3,4,1]
```

### Move array element using `flatMap` where time complexity is Linear Time - O(n)

```js
function arrayMove(arr, oldIndex, newIndex) {
    const length = arr.length;
    const itemToMove = arr[oldIndex]

    if (oldIndex === newIndex || oldIndex > length || newIndex > length) {
        return arr;
    }

    return arr.flatMap((item, index) => {
        if (index === oldIndex) return [];
        if (index === newIndex) return oldIndex < newIndex ? [item, itemToMove] : [itemToMove, item];
        return item;
    })
}

arrayMove([1,2,3,4], 0, 3) // [2,3,4,1]
```

### Move array element using `reduce` where time complexity is Linear Time - O(n)

```js
function arrayMove(arr, oldIndex, newIndex) {
    const length = arr.length;
    const itemToMove = arr[oldIndex]

    if (oldIndex === newIndex || oldIndex > length || newIndex > length) {
        return arr;
    }

    return arr.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
        if (index === oldIndex) return acc;
        if (index === newIndex) return oldIndex < newIndex ? [...acc, item, itemToMove] : [...acc, itemToMove, item];
        return [...acc, item];
    }, [])
}

arrayMove([1,2,3,4], 0, 3) // [2,3,4,1]
```

You can also checkout this gist: [Move an array element from one array position to another](https://gist.github.com/foyez/f6afb78897542cceb3807faacbc84f02)

Comment: Why do you spread the accumulated array several times in the reducer loop? Simply use push? I'm just wondering why you see the need to copy the array inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple mutable solution without any `splice` or other array functions with complexity of `O(n)` without using any memory allocations.

If the desired index is out of array boundaries, it will move element to end/start of the array.

```
function moveArray(arr, from, to) {
    if (from >= arr.length || from < 0) throw Error('Out of boundaries'); // cover edge cases for moving element
    const increment = from > to ? -1 : 1; // where to move others (up/down)
    to = increment > 0 ? Math.min(to, arr.length - 1) : Math.max(to, 0); // cover edge cases for placement (start/end)
    if (from === to) return;
    const target = arr[from];
    while (from !== to) arr[from] = arr[(from += increment)]; // move elements in between
    arr[to] = target; // place target at desired index
}

// test/example
const arr = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
moveArray(arr, 2, 4);

console.log(arr); // [ 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8 ]

moveArray(arr, 3, 11);
console.log(arr); // [ 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 8, 6 ]

moveArray(arr, 6, -1);
console.log(arr); // [ 6, 2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 8 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

@abr's answer is near perfect, but it misses one edge case where if you try and access a key that does not exist in the array, it actually returns an array 1 entry larger than the original. This fixes that bug.

```
let move = (arr, from, to) => {
        const smallerIndex = Math.min(from, to);
        const largerIndex = Math.max(from, to);
        
        /**
            Bail early if array does not have the target key, to avoid 
            edge case where trying to move an undefined key
            results in the array growing 1 entry in size with an undefined value
        */
        
        if(!arr.hasOwnProperty(from)) return arr
    
        return [
            
            ...arr.slice(0, smallerIndex),
            
            ...(
                from < to
                    ? arr.slice(smallerIndex + 1, largerIndex + 1)
                    : []
            ),
            
            arr[from],
    
            ...(
                from > to
                    ? arr.slice(smallerIndex, largerIndex)
                    : []
            ),
    
            ...arr.slice(largerIndex + 1),
    
        ];
    }
    
    
    let arr = [
        0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    ];
    console.log(move(arr, -30, -45));
    console.log(move(arr, 0, -45));
    console.log(move(arr, 0, 1));
    console.log(move(arr, 0, 0));
    console.log(move(arr, 5, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

With Angular U could use the angular/cdk/drag-drop API.
Either when actually using drag&drop or as standalone:

`npm install @angular/cdk`

app.module.ts:

```
import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
```

In componentXY.ts:

```
import { CdkDragDrop, CdkDragEnd, CdkDragStart, moveItemInArray } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

  onDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<any>) {
    // handle drop event
    console.log("onDrop", event)
    moveItemInArray(this.codes, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to convert from Object to array, move the index than reconvert in Object

```js
 function x(obje, oldIndex, newIndex) {
        var newArr = Object.entries(obje);
        var finalObj = new Object();
        newArr.splice(newIndex,0,newArr.splice(oldIndex,1)[0]);
        //-- Convert again in object
        finalObj = newArr.reduce( (obj, item) => Object.assign(obj, { [item[0]]: item[1] }), {});
        return finalObj;
    }
var obj = {
  "x.pdf": {
    "sizeFmt": " <samp>(107.64 KB)</samp>"
  },
  "y.pdf": {
    "sizeFmt": " <samp>(364.34 KB)</samp>"
  },
  "z.pdf": {
    "sizeFmt": " <samp>(111.81 KB)</samp>"
  }
};
console.log(obj);
obj = x(obj, 0, 1);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using modern JavaScript (as of 2023) without mutating the array:

```js
function move(array, targetIndex, beforeIndex) {
  if (targetIndex < beforeIndex) {
    // Moves forward
    return [
      ...array.slice(0, targetIndex),
      ...array.slice(targetIndex + 1, beforeIndex),
      array.at(targetIndex),
      ...array.slice(beforeIndex),
    ];
  }

  if (targetIndex > beforeIndex) {
    // Moves back
    return [
      ...array.slice(0, beforeIndex),
      array.at(targetIndex),
      ...array.slice(beforeIndex, targetIndex),
      ...array.slice(targetIndex + 1),
    ];
  }
  
  // Stayes in place
  return [...array];
}

const letters = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

// Move te d back, before the b
console.log(move(letters, letters.indexOf("d"), letters.indexOf("b")));

// Move the b forward, before the d
console.log(move(letters, letters.indexOf("b"), letters.indexOf("d")));

// Have the c stay in place
console.log(move(letters, letters.indexOf("c"), 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

var array = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

const fromIndex = array.indexOf('e');

const toIndex = 1;

const element = array.splice(fromIndex, 1)[0];

array.splice(toIndex, 0, element);

console.log(array).

// output   ['a','e', 'b', 'c', 'd']