# How can I move a model within a collection?

Tags: collections, model, backbone.js

Say I'm having a plain `Backbone.Collection` with some models in it:

```
var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Book
});

lib = new Library(
   [Book1, Book2, Book3, Book4, Book5, Book6]
]);
```

How can I move a model within a collection - e.g. the 5th one to the 2nd position? So no sorting by a model field but just changing the sort order manually.

*Note: I simplified the models `Book1, ...`. They are of course `Backbone.Model`s.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly access the array of models to modify the order. Loosely based on this question [Move an array element from one array position to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306680/move-an-array-element-from-one-array-position-to-another), something like this should work:

```
var c = new Backbone.Collection([{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}, {id: 5}]);
console.log(c.pluck("id"));

var from_ix = 4,
    to_ix = 1;
c.models.splice(to_ix, 0, c.models.splice(from_ix, 1)[0]);
console.log(c.pluck("id"));
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/5DGJs/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I completely forgot about the `collection.models` array and thought there must be some functionality within `Collection`. I missed the forest for the trees ;-)