# How to convert an array of strings to keyed object in javascript/lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Given the array:

```
var arr = [ "one", "two", "three" ];
```

Whats the cleanest way to convert it to:

```
{ "one": true, "two": true, "three": true }
```

I tried the following but I imagine there is a better way.

```
 _.zipObject(arr || {}, _.fill([], true, 0, arr.length))
```

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer yes I tried:  _.zipObject(sets.Seen || {}, _.fill([], true, 0, sets.Seen.length))

Comment: Then best if you just include it in the post then.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Edited the Q

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var obj = arr.reduce(function(o, v) { return o[v] = true, o; }, {});
```

Comment: This is the first time I've seen the comma operator on `return`. Interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284536/return-statement-with-multiple-comma-seperated-values

Answer (score 1):

Using `lodash`:

```js
const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

_.mapValues(_.keyBy(arr), () => true);
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple way would be like this:

```
function toObject(arr) {
   var rv = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
   rv[i] = true;
   return rv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = ["one", "two", "three"];
var myObject = new Object();

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    myObject[array[i]] = true;
}

console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: Don't use `new Object()`, use an object literal instead `{}`