# When reading minified Javascript, how am I supposed to read this return statement with commas, &&, and || operators?

Tags: javascript, minify

I have this source code:

```
function findMessageErrors(btn) {
    var error = "";
    var message = $(btn).parent().siblings().find("textarea[name='message']").val();
    if (message === "") {
        error += "*Please enter a message.<br/>";
    }
    if (!$(btn).parent().siblings().find('input[name="agree"]').prop('checked')) {
        error += "*Please agree.<br/>";
    }
    return error;
}
```

This gets minified.  After minification, it looks like this in the Chrome Dev tools Sources tab:

```
function findMessageErrors(btn) {
    var error = "";
    return "" === $(btn).parent().siblings().find("textarea[name='message']").val() && (error += "*Please enter a message.<br/>"),
    $(btn).parent().siblings().find('input[name="agree"]').prop("checked") || (error += "*Please agree.<br/>"),
    error
}
```

I understand how the comma operator 'runs a series of expressions, in order, and then returns the result of the last of them' [(from here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284536/return-statement-with-multiple-comma-separated-values).  But I'm having a hard time understanding how those OR and AND operators are working in building that string that gets returned in the minified code.

Does anyone have a helpful way of reading that out loud that will help me understand how that works?   I guess I don't see how 2 independent IF statements in the source gets minified into a series of && then ||.  I don't want to have to look up the source every time I want to understand the logic of how the minified code works.

Comment: How about just not reading midified code? It's not meant for human consumption.

Comment: *"I don't want to have to look up the source every time I want to understand the logic of how the minified code works."* Don't. Use source maps.

Comment: Just in case it isn't clear, TJ means the technology which you can find a description of here: [MDN: Use a source map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map).

Comment: Not sure why a downvote.. I just wanted to know the logic of how this works.  (now I know this to be short circuit evaluation.. thanks to the reply to this post)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where possible, use [source maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map) rather than trying to read minified code.

But that doesn't mean you don't want to know how to read complex statements; sometimes humans write them. :-)

I've done some formatting and inline comments to explain:

```
function findMessageErrors(btn) {
    var error = "";
    return (
        (
            "" === $(btn).parent().siblings().find("textarea[name='message']").val()
            &&
            // This only runs if the === above is true, because of the &&
            (error += "*Please enter a message.<br/>")
        )
        ,
        ( // This runs regardless of the above
            $(btn).parent().siblings().find('input[name="agree"]').prop("checked")
            ||
            // This only runs if prop("checked") returned a falsy value, because of ||
            (error += "*Please agree.<br/>")
        )
        ,
        ( // This runs regardless, of the above...
            // ...and this is the ultimate value of the return
            error
        )
    );
}
```

The outer `()` are just added because a linebreak after `return` triggers (the horror that is) automatic semicolon insertion. Other `()` are added for clarity of explanation.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Your comments helped me wrap my head around what's going on.  I am aware of source maps and will use it, but just thought this was something that I should know about Javascript.   Thanks again.

Comment: To further elaborate, the core of the 'magic' here in each of the statements is [short circuit evaulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) for `&&` and `||`.