# Loop through ListView for matching calendar selectedDate

Tags: javascript, arrays, listview, qml, v-play

I am looking to populate a `listView` of events on the currently `selectedDate` of a calendar with data from an array(`calendarListModel`)

When a new date is selected from the calendar, I need the list to update, clearing and remaining empty if no events exist on the newly selected date, or replacing the listView with new delegates matching the newly selectedDate.

My array is created from a read from a firebase database, which works as intended. An example of my array would be;

```
calendarListModel: [
    {"date":2019-02-12,"name":"user1"},
    {"date":2019-02-13","name":"user1"},
    {"date":2019-02-12,"name":"user2"}
]
```

If I set my model as `calendarListModel` My list shows every database entry regardless of date on the `listView`.

I have tried things such as;

`model: calendarListView.date(calendar.selectedDate`

also using loops to access the data, which i have had no success with, and most recently the following example;

```
function updateEvents() {
                    var eventModel = calendarListModel.find(
                                function(obj){
                                return obj.date === calendar.selectedDate.getDate(),
                                console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
                                }
                            );
                    if (eventModel === undefined)
                        return eventListModel.length = [];
                    return eventListModel.push(eventModel)
                }

Calendar {
        id: calendar
        selectedDate: new Date()

        onSelectedDateChanged: {
            const day = selectedDate.getDate();
            const month = selectedDate.getMonth() + 1;
            const year = selectedDate.getFullYear();
            updateEvents()
        }
    }

            ListView {
            id:eventListView
            model: eventListModel
        }
```

My console log from the `JSON.stringify(obj)` seems to split my array into individual objects, with the logs showing:

`{"date":1549972800000,"name":"user1"}
 {"date":1550059200000,"name":"user1"}
 {"date":1549972800000,"name":"user2"}`

but when doing this `eventListView` and `eventModel` remain blank?

What can i do to correct this or what direction to i need to work in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you've passed into `find` is faulty.

```
function(obj) {
    return obj.date === calendar.selectedDate.getDate(),     // <-- oh no! lé comma!
        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

Note that you used the comma operator which, in JS, will throw away the expression on the left and return the result of the right (`undefined` here, since that's what `console.log` returns). A quick test on a JS console shows that this does not produce and return the desired results (a boolean in your case).

```
function comma() {
    return 1, console.log('blunder');
}
function noComma {
    console.log('success');
    return 1;
}

x = comma();    // blunder
y = noComma();  // success

console.log(x);  // undefined   //  but expected 1 ?!?
console.log(y);  // 1
```

You're probably after something like this:

```
function(obj) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

    return obj.date === calendar.selectedDate.getDate();
}
```

However, this compares a... string (?) to an integer (returned by `getDate()`). You may want to instead do

```
return new Date(obj.date).getDate() === calendar.selectedDate.getDate();
```

This still logs `obj` while returning a boolean.

[*Read more about JavaScript's comma operator...*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284536/return-statement-with-multiple-comma-separated-values)

Comment: Hey @TrebuchetMS thanks for the response, both matching and missing dates are needed as they will either clear the list (non matching date) or create the `ListView` (matching date), I changed my code to your suggestion but receive no console log with the date or Boolean? when the selected date is changed (should trigger the function to do its job) the function is currently within `onSelectedDateChanged: {….}` part of my calendar, I am working with v-play(now Felgo) if that would make a difference? Thanks again

Comment: Hi I've changed my last code snippet and removed the if-statement. Seems like you're wanting to log all objects.  So far, it looks like a QML/JS -only problem (so V-Play/Felgo don't really make a difference)... unless you're having some other problem I'm not seeing...