# JavaScript Trying to make a clock for html, can't tell what's broken

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, clock

JavaScript Trying to make a clock for html, can't tell what's broken.
This js clock works fine on a Sharepoint site, but I'm trying to implement it on a local file and it somehow broke along the way. I'm trying to use `getElementById` to find the `<span id>` and change the text to the current time. I can't tell what exactly is broken. 
Thank you for taking a look. [Original JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1mL97erv/1/), [Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k8z4ju1d/2/). 
UPDATE: I tried to tidy up the code and now instead of a blank `<span>` it now gives me a `false` output. So I guess you could say progress was made. I still don't exactly know whats broken, but the quest continues!
UPDATE 2: Thanks to StackSlave, did a bit of formatting, here is the [Final JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wk57a2z9/), it works just fine in Chrome, but JSFiddle doesn't quite like it. Thank you to all who helped me in this endeavor.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', Elements, false);
window.addEventListener('load', getElement, false);
window.addEventListener('load', worldClock, false);

  function Elements() {
    getElement("Zulu", worldClock(0, "NODST") );
    getElement("NewYork", worldClock(-9, "NAmerica"));
    setTimeout(Elements, 1e3);
  }

  function getElement(Id, time) {
      var a = document.getElementById(Id);
        if (a)
          a.innerHTML = time;
        else {
            return
          }
  }

  function worldClock(offset, timezone){
    var common = 0;
        a = new Date(new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 6e4);
        getDate = a.getDate();
        getMonth = a.getMonth();
        getYear = a.getYear();
    return a.getYear < 1e3 && (a.getYear += 1900);
            monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
            days = ["31", "28", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31"],
            getYear % 4 == 0 && (days = ["31", "28", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31"]),
            getYear % 100 == 0 && getYear % 400 != 0 && (days = ["31", "28", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31"]),
            w = 0,
            offset != 0 && offset % 1 != 0 && (w = offset % 1 * 60),
            l = a.getMinutes() + w,
            l > 59 ? (e = a.getHours() + Math.floor(n) + 1,
            l -= 60) : e = a.getHours() + Math.floor(n),
            y = a.getSeconds(),
            e >= 24 && (e = e - 24,
            s -= -1),
            e < 0 && (e -= -24,
            s -= 1),
            e < 10 && (e = " " + e),
            l < 10 && (l = "0" + 1),
            y < 10 && (y = "0" + y),
            s <= 0 && (0 == 0 ? (o = 11,
            getYear -= 1) : o = o - 1,
            s = days[0]),
            s > days[0] && (s = 1,
            o == 11 ? (o = 0,
            getYear -= 1) : o -= -1),
            t == "NODST" && (c = 0),
            t == "NAmerica" && (u = new Date(),
            i = new Date(),
            u.setMonth(2),
            u.setHours(2),
            u.setDate(13),
            f = u.getDay(),
            f != 0 ? u.setDate(8 - f) : u.setDate(1),
            i.setMonth(9),
            i.setHours(1),
            i.setDate(31),
            f = i.getDay(),
            i.setDate(31 - f),
            r = new Date(),
            r.setMonth(o),
            r.setYear(h),
            r.setDate(s),
            r.setHours(e),
            r >= u && r < i && (c = 1));
  }
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <script type="text/jscript" src="./clock.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="clock">
      New York:
      <span id="NewYork"> </span>
      Zulu:
      <span id="Zulu"> </span>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This code is really bad. Is it minified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's keey this simple:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
var doc, bod, I, ClockMaker; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
ClockMaker = function(output, offset){
  this.clocks = [];
  var t = this;
  function out(a){
    var o = a[1] || 0, dt = new Date(3600000*o+Date.now());
    a[0].innerHTML = dt.toUTCString();
  }
  setInterval(function(){
    t.clocks.forEach(out);
  }, 10);
  this.clock = function(output, offset){
    this.clocks.push([output, offset]);
    return this;
  }
}
var clocks = new ClockMaker;
clocks.clock(I('ny'), -5).clock(I('zu'));
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
html,body{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
h2{
  margin:5px 7px;
}
h2,h2+div{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Simple Clock</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
 <div><h2>New York:</h2><div id='ny'></div><div>
 <div><h2>Zulu:</h2><div id='zu'></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can access `dt` to use other UTC methods.

Answer (score 1):

From the beginning when setting the timeout you use as callback a lowercase "time" and it is not the function, but it's returning value because of the "()"

```
setTimeout(time(), 1e3);
```

if I understood well should be:

```
 setTimeout(Time, 1e3);
```

maybe it is not enough to make it work, but surely it is enough to not make it work.

Comment: I changed it like you said, had no apparent effect.

Comment: I did not say it would make it work. As I can see at first glance the variable "monthnames" and all that follows is after a return statement, and what is returned is a boolean value (true/false), maybe the one you say you see on the page.
I wonder if you really need that obscure worldClock function to achieve what you want. 
I'd rather read the documentation of Date (for example [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date))

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely unreadable, you should definitely reconsider your variable naming and structure. Two things from skimming through it:

- You are not returning a list by returning a comma-separated list of expressions. The [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284536/return-statement-with-multiple-comma-separated-values) only returns the last value in the list, so `worldClock` will return `r >= u && r < i && (c = 1))`
- You are not passing a reference to the `Time` function to `setTimeout`, you are passing the result of a function call. You meant `setTimeout(Time, 1e3)`
- The function is called `Time`, you are trying `setTimeout` with `time`. JS is case-sensitive, rename your function to `time`

I would be surprised if the function works though, in my experience unreadable code is unreliable code. But try it out and tell me if it works! Good luck!

Comment: I agree with you on it being unreadable, the original version that I pulled was worse. I corrected the capitalization and `setTimeout` like you said, it didn't have any apparent effect. I'm going to take a look at the `function worldClock` and try to sort through it. I appreciate the help @dev