# Why i get a empty array after position moved?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I try to use code from this [Move an array element from one array position to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306680/move-an-array-element-from-one-array-position-to-another) to move arrays position

But why when i will move **last to first** so I get a empty array

i do like this...

```
my_array.move(my_array_length,0);
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Jsu7R/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since javascript arrays are indexed from 0 upwards, your code:

```
my_array.move(my_array_length,0);
```

will need to change to :

```
my_array.move(my_array_length-1,0);
```

The length of your array has 5 elements, but the last element has an index of 4.

Comment: You might also consider changing the function to either pferform a no-op or throw an error if the old index is outside the bounds of the array

Answer (score 2):

The method "move" from the reference page gets old_index, new_index parameters.
You supply the array's length as the first parameter, but your array has no element at this position.

If you call "move" with these parameters:

```
my_array.move(my_array_length - 1,0)
```

it will work as expected