# d3.js chart interaction causes HTML5 drag and drop to stop working

Tags: html, angularjs, d3.js, html5-draggable

I'm using HTML5 drag and drop to create some sortable tabs. Here's the exact code although it's Angular specific: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23443028/1267778

I have an svg chart using d3.js inside one of those tabs.

The sortability works but when I click on the chart, it does a transition and the sortability is now broken until I reload the page.

I have other svg charts in others tabs that I can interact with without breaking it, however the chart that causes problems doesn't throw any error or anything. It just breaks without any clues as to what happened.

I note that the ".dragging" class is still being applied when I start dragging, but there is no drag or drop effect; the tab stays in place.

Any idea as to what might be happening or where I can start looking for problem? I'm not really even sure where to start since no errors are thrown and I don't see how the drag and drop could possibly relate to me clicking the chart unless javascript crashed but there is no sign of that.

Comment: Can you post a plunker showing the issue?

Comment: @Michal unfortunately I can't the entire chart is too much code ~1000 lines. Doesn't seem like I'll be able to reproduce being that other charts work fine. Where would you look?

Comment: Alas no idea... But one way of debugging is to start removing or simplifying things. At some point things will either work, or you'll have a short enough example to post.

Comment: Just I'm case: if the dragged element's content changes during drag -- like nodes getting added or removed intentionally or not -- that could prematurely cancel the drag.