# How to move up and down items using angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

http://jsfiddle.net/Nidhin/xd3Ab/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
 myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.roles = [
    {roleId: 1, roleName: "Administrator"},
    {roleId: 2, roleName: "Super User"}
];

$scope.user = {
    userId: 1, 
    username: "JimBob",
    roles: [$scope.roles[0]]
};});myApp.directive('multiSelect', function($q) {return {
restrict: 'E',
require: 'ngModel',
scope: {
  selectedLabel: "@",
  availableLabel: "@",
  displayAttr: "@",
  available: "=",
  model: "=ngModel"
},
template: '<div class="multiSelect">' + 
            '<div class="leftms fL ">' +
              '<label class="control-label fL" for="multiSelectSelected">{{ availableLabel }} ' +
                  '({{ available.length }})</label>'+'<div class="clear"></div>'+
              '<select id="multiSelectAvailable"  ng-model="selected.available" multiple ' +
                  'class="pull-left mselect " ng-options="e as e[displayAttr] for e in available"></select>' + '<div class="clear"></div>'+
            '</div>'  + 
            '<div class=" width10p fL" >' + 
              '<button class="btn mover left" ng-click="add()" title="Add selected" ' + 
                  'ng-disabled="selected.available.length == 0">' + 
                '<i class="icon-arrow-right clrblk">&gt;</i>' + 
              '</button>' +
              '<button class="btn mover right" ng-click="remove()" title="Remove selected" ' + 
                  'ng-disabled="selected.current.length == 0">' + 
                '<i class="icon-arrow-left clrblk">&lt;</i>' + 
              '</button>' +
            '</div>' + 
            '<div class="leftms fL">' + 
              '<label class="control-label fL" for="multiSelectSelected">{{ selectedLabel }} ' +
                  '({{ model.length }})</label>' +'<div class="clear"></div>'+
              '<select id="currentRoles" ng-model="selected.current" multiple ' + 
                  'class="pull-left mselect fL" ng-options="e as e[displayAttr] for e in model">' + 
                  '</select>' + '<div class="clear"></div>'+
            '</div>' +
            '<div class=" width10p fL" >' + 
              '<button class="btn mover left" ng-click="up()" title="Add selected" ' + 
                  'ng-disabled="selected.current.length == 0">' + 
                '<i class="fa fa-angle-up clrblk"></i>' + 
              '</button>' +
              '<button class="btn mover right" ng-click="down()" title="Remove selected" ' + 
                  'ng-disabled="selected.current.length == 0">' + 
                '<i  class="fa fa-angle-down clrblk"></i>' + 
              '</button>' +
            '</div>' +
          '</div>',  link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      scope.selected = {
        available: [],
        current: []
      };

      /* Handles cases where scope data hasn't been initialized yet */
      var dataLoading = function(scopeAttr) {
        var loading = $q.defer();
        if(scope[scopeAttr]) {
          loading.resolve(scope[scopeAttr]);
        } else {
          scope.$watch(scopeAttr, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if(newValue !== undefined)
              loading.resolve(newValue);
          });  
        }
        return loading.promise;
      };

      /* Filters out items in original that are also in toFilter. Compares by reference. */
      var filterOut = function(original, toFilter) {
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(original, function(entity) {
          var match = false;
          for(var i = 0; i < toFilter.length; i++) {
            if(toFilter[i][attrs.displayAttr] == entity[attrs.displayAttr]) {
              match = true;
              break;
            }
          }
          if(!match) {
            filtered.push(entity);
          }
        });
        return filtered;
      };

      scope.refreshAvailable = function() {
        scope.available = filterOut(scope.available, scope.model);
        scope.selected.available = [];
        scope.selected.current = [];
      }; 

      scope.add = function() {
        scope.model = scope.model.concat(scope.selected.available);
        scope.refreshAvailable();
      };
      scope.remove = function() {
        scope.available = scope.available.concat(scope.selected.current);
        scope.model = filterOut(scope.model, scope.selected.current);
        scope.refreshAvailable();
      };

      scope.update = function() {
        scope.model = scope.model.concat(scope.selected.current);
        //scope.model = filterOut(scope.model, scope.selected.current);
        scope.refreshAvailable();
      };

      scope.up = function() {
        var $op = $('#currentRoles option:selected');
        if($op.length){
            $op.first().prev().before($op);
        }
        $('#currentRoles').find('option').attr('selected','selected');
        //scope.update();
        scope.refreshAvailable();
      };

      scope.down = function() {
        var $op = $('#currentRoles option:selected');
        if($op.length){
            $op.last().next().after($op);
        }
        //scope.add();
        scope.refreshAvailable();
        scope.apply();
      };

      $q.all([dataLoading("model"), dataLoading("available")]).then(function(results) {
        scope.refreshAvailable();
  });
}};})// JavaScript Document
```

on this link you will find two select box Available Role & Current role, I have to move item from Available Role to Current role Then Move the item Up and down in Current role Select box
--- Moving Item from available role to Current role I have used angular js
--- For Moving item UP and down in Current role I have used Jquery But when I am posting the value order of item is not passing in same format which is in Current role selectbox.

Pls use the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion, you should just modify the arrays within $scope to get the ordering right.

https://gist.github.com/jfornoff/db2bb5f0c35bc0364529
This is a gist of a bit of code that i used to modify array orders in a project that i worked on.

Basically what you would do is just grab your variable that points to the currently selected element,
and modify the corresponding array to suit what you are trying to do.

```
$scope.up = function(){
  ArrayService.moveUp(correspondingArray, selected.current);
};
```

Hope that helps, cheers!

Comment: Can you please update the fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/Nidhin/xd3Ab/ ) with your code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular itself to move elements up and down too. If you reorder the elements in the array `available` and `current` the ui would automatically reorder the elements.
Use the array `splice` method to move element within the array. See this answer on how to move elements in an array.

[Move an array element from one array position to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306680/move-an-array-element-from-one-array-position-to-another)