# JavaScript: Re-order an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I read a few answers on SO about the problems when dealing with splice (including [Move an array element from one array position to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306680/move-an-array-element-from-one-array-position-to-another)) but I was unable to solve my problem.

I am trying to reorder an array in a particular pattern. Let's assume the pattern is that all the **negative numbers** should be to the **left** of the array and all the **postive** numbers should be to the **right** of the array. The negative and positive numbers should be separated by **zeros** if any. **It is important that the order be maintained**

```
Sample Input   = [3,0,2,-1,0,-3]
Desired Output = [-1,-3,0,0,3,2]
```

This is the code I wrote

```
function reorderArray(inputArray) {
origLength = inputArray.length
var indexZero = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < origLength; i++) {
    if (inputArray[i] > 0) {
        inputArray.push(inputArray[i]);
        inputArray.splice(i, 1);
    } else if (indexZero == -1 && inputArray[i] == 0) {
        indexZero = i;
    } else if (indexZero != -1 && inputArray[i] < 0) {
        inputArray.splice(indexZero, 0, inputArray.splice(i, 1))
        indexZero++;
    }
  }
alert(inputArray);
}
```

I run into a problem in the first step itself where I attempt to move all positive numbers at the back of the array because of the re-indexing. I can't start from the last index because that would mean losing the order and I can't use the **i--** since it would run infinitely.

Any help with how I could make my code work would be appreciated. Additionally, if there is an alternative that is more efficient than splice, that would be welcome too.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure I get it, looks like you're describing a standard Array.sort -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/5ncfb2uu/**, but without the order

Comment: Or you could do this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/5ncfb2uu/1/**

Comment: As order is important, you may find it easier to filter into 3 separate arrays of -ves,0s,+ves then put them back together

Comment: I also think it's better to filter values into 3 different arrays. Than in the end, you still can concat those 3 arrays into 1.

Comment: Thanks everyone. My first approach was 3 separate arrays but I wasn't sure of the space complexity ramifications. Any help on that?

Comment: @adeneo: Thank you but that does cause a problem if there are duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var input = [3,0,2,-1,0,-3];

var copy = input.slice(0); // you need an original array copy since you need to
                           // refer to it to maintain the original order

input.sort(function(a, b) {
    var sign_a = Math.sign(a),
        sign_b = Math.sign(b);

    if (sign_a != sign_b) {
        return sign_a - sign_b;
    }

    return copy.indexOf(a) - copy.indexOf(b);
});

console.log(input);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w2g195fy/2/

So you first compare numbers by sign, then you guarantee sort stability by comparing the positions in the original array. The latter is **IMPORTANT** since `Array.prototype.sort()` is **not guaranteed** to be stable.

**Another important note**: the complexity (from number of comparisons point of view) of this particular implementation is `O(N^2 * logN)` which may be not acceptable if you have large original array.

**Yet another important note**: it will not work in case if your input array has duplicate values.

This is a naive implementation that will work with duplicates:

```
var input = [1, -1, 2, 0, -2, 3, 0, -3, -4, 4, 0];

var groups = input.reduce(function(result, item) {
    result[Math.sign(item)].push(item);
    return result;
}, {'-1': [], 0: [], 1: []});

var result = groups['-1'].concat(groups[0]).concat(groups[1]);

console.log(result)
```

And here is the most efficient (from both memory and number of comparisons point of view - it's `O(N)`) solution I can think of:

```
var input = [1, -4, 2, 0, -2, 3, 0, -3, -4, 4, 0];

var result = [];

for (var sign = -1, len = input.length; sign <= 1; ++sign) {
    for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (Math.sign(input[i]) == sign) {
            result.push(input[i]);
        }
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pbmw4dtt/

Comment: Thank you. This does work but like you pointed out, the complexity is a problem and it won't work if there are duplicates. Do you suppose I could replace the positive numbers with undefined in my code? And then have a second run to get rid of the undefined?

Comment: @Sid: "the complexity is a problem" --- put some constraints into the question then

Comment: Sorry about that. There aren't any constraints to start off and I'm terrible at calculating Complexity so I don't even know the probable complexity that my code would eventually have. But I was trying to get to as optimum a solution as possible. Sorry again. The duplicates bit is still a problem though, correct?

Comment: @Sid What's the problem with duplicates? How should they be handled?

Comment: @plalx: In the order they appear. So if it's [-3, -1, 0, 2, -3], it should output [-3, -1, -3, 0, 2]

Comment: @plalx and zerkms: This is the change I made to my code and it seems to be working. But I'm not sure of the space/time complexity. Is it an overkill? http://jsfiddle.net/jceemyen/ Thanks.

Comment: @Sid Did you look at my implementation?

Comment: @Sid: "Is it an overkill?" --- does it fit your performance/complexity/memory constraints?

Comment: The thing is, these were the kind of questions that were asked in interviews etc. so they ask for as efficient solutions as possible. In both, Time and Space.

Comment: @Sid: then you just iterate over your array 3 times and push data to a new array. `O(N)` for both comparison number and memory. I wouldn't do it like you in place, since it's `O(N^2)`

Comment: Boy! Your codes show that I clearly have a lot to learn by way of library functions. It took me a while to figure it all out. Thanks a lot though.

Answer (score 1):

Another way with of doing it with `sort`:

```
[3,0,2,-1,0,-3].map(function () { return arguments; }).sort(function (a, b) {
    var aNum = a[0],
        bNum = b[0],
        bothNegative = aNum < 0 && aNum < 0,
        bothPositive = aNum > 0 && bNum > 0;

    if (bothNegative || bothPositive) return a[1] - b[1];
    return aNum - bNum;

}).map(function (arr) { return arr[0]; });
```

The initial items order is preserved, but they are now segregated in 3 groups. Negatives, zeros and positives.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be a solution:

```
var input = [3,0,2,-1,0,-3].join('+');
var output = input.match(/-\d+/g).concat( input.match(/0/g) ).concat( input.match(/(^|\+)[1-9]\d*/g) ).map(parseFloat);
```

And [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ep3gp856/).

It is slower than `sort` because of last array `map` (which can be omitted), but idea may be useful.