# close popover by clicking other tabs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I am new to angular js, i want to create tabbing which can be rename and can be switch positions inter-between, i have created dome Here's [a link] (http://plnkr.co/edit/sIQevsrtTStDvqvG9ot4?p=preview ), i want to close popover when click on other tabs after rename

```
     <html ng-app="MyTabsUI">
          <head>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>
            <script src="mindit.js"></script>
            <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
          </head>
          <body>
          <div class="container" ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">

            <div class="col-md-12">
            <tabset >
                    <tab ng-model='newTab' popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl"
                    popover-placement="bottom" sortable-tab ng-repeat="tab in data.tabs"
                    heading="{{tab.name}}" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled" index='{{$index}}' 
                    class="closePopover clickbtn"  rel='popover' >
                        <div class="column">

                        </div>
                      <script type="text/ng-template" id="myPopoverTemplate.html"  >
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Enter Title : </label>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="tab.name" class="form-control">
                          </div>
                      </script>
                   </tab>
                    <tab>
                    <tab-heading>
                    <i ng-click="add()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">Groups</i>
                    </tab-heading>
                     </tab>
                  </tabset>
                </div>
          </div>
          </body>
        </html>


angularjs


var app = angular.module('MyTabsUI', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('TabsDemoCtrl', function ($scope,$http) {
  var cnt=0
  $scope.data = [];
  $scope.data.tabs = [ ];
  $scope.result ;
    /* for adding tabs*/
    $scope.add = function() 
    {
      cnt++; /* used to limet the tabing adding functions*/
      if(cnt < 4){
              $scope.isDisabled = false;
             // var iniTab = [{'header':'1'},{'datacontent':'datacontent'}];       intTab: iniTab,
              $scope.data.tabs.push({name:'Dynamic Title'});
              return $scope.data.tabs;  
      }else{
               $scope.isDisabled = true;
              return false;
      }
    };

    /* to rename tabs*/
    $scope.dynamicPopover = {
        content: 'hello',
        templateUrl: 'myPopoverTemplate.html',
        title: 'Title'
    };
});
app.directive('sortableTab', function() 
{
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
      // Attempt to integrate with ngRepeat
      // https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L211
      var match = attrs.ngRepeat.match(/^\s*([\s\S]+?)\s+in\s+([\s\S]+?)(?:\s+track\s+by\s+([\s\S]+?))?\s*$/);
      var tabs;
      scope.$watch(match[2], function(newTabs) {
        tabs = newTabs;
      });
      var index = scope.$index;
      scope.$watch('$index', function(newIndex) {
        index = newIndex;
      });
      attrs.$set('draggable', true);
      // Wrapped in $apply so Angular reacts to changes
      var wrappedListeners = {
        // On item being dragged
        dragstart: function(e) {
          e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
          e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
          e.dataTransfer.setData('application/json', index);
          element.addClass('dragging');
        },
        dragend: function(e) {
          //e.stopPropagation();
          element.removeClass('dragging');
        },
        // On item being dragged over / dropped onto
        dragenter: function(e) {
        },
        dragleave: function(e) {
          element.removeClass('hover');
        },
        drop: function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          var sourceIndex = e.dataTransfer.getData('application/json');
          move(sourceIndex, index);
          element.removeClass('hover');
        }
      };
      // For performance purposes, do not
      // call $apply for these
      var unwrappedListeners = {
        dragover: function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          element.addClass('hover');
        },
        /* Use .hover instead of :hover. :hover doesn't play well with 
           moving DOM from under mouse when hovered */
        mouseenter: function() {
          element.addClass('hover');
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
          element.removeClass('hover');
        }
      };
      angular.forEach(wrappedListeners, function(listener, event) {
        element.on(event, wrap(listener));
      });
      angular.forEach(unwrappedListeners, function(listener, event) {
        element.on(event, listener);
      });
      function wrap(fn) {
        return function(e) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            fn(e);
          });
        };
      }
      function move(fromIndex, toIndex) {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/a/7180095/1319998
        tabs.splice(toIndex, 0, tabs.splice(fromIndex, 1)[0]);
      }
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/FKGkrlkoHEAzvYEWZyO5?p=preview  i have refer this but if we put input field it doesn't work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You must be expecting this , i think 
>   http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/0LkRYTVMPoRx8d6qzfqh/

Answer (score 3):

myhtml.html

```
<div class="bs-example tooltip-demo">
    <div class="bs-example-tooltips">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="You clicked first button" data-original-title="" title="">Button1</button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="You clicked second button" data-original-title="" title="">Button2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

myscript.js

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
        //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

Kindly refer this below link for bootstrap popover.

http://jsfiddle.net/parthipans/nrha8m10/1/

Comment: its great solutions sir but i accepting something different as if we use input field in it then that time your solutions does not work, i insists you will it possible only with angular js only

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/sIQevsrtTStDvqvG9ot4?p=preview    as if we add group then new tab is generated and click on to rename it popover is open but if we click outside it never closed iff click on same tab

Comment: my questions is ...
i want to close popover if it content input field....
here is demo
http://plnkr.co/edit/sIQevsrtTStDvqvG9ot4?p=preview
add groups and click on the tabs then rename tab but if we click outside then it doesn't close, it closed iff we click on same tab