# Swap json values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to swap the first row and second row by using jquery on button click. Is there any json predefined function to swap two array of json.

```
  var arr = [
           { "ID": 135, "Name": "Fargo Chan", "Address": "34, Baker Street" },
           { "ID": 432, "Name": "Aaron Luke", "Address": "BLDG 1, J Street" },
           { "ID": 252, "Name": "Dilip Singh", "Address": "Hotel J, SE" }
         ];

  var arr = [
          { "ID": 432, "Name": "Aaron Luke", "Address": "BLDG 1, J Street" },
          { "ID": 135, "Name": "Fargo Chan", "Address": "34, Baker Street" },     
          { "ID": 252, "Name": "Dilip Singh", "Address": "Hotel J, SE" }
       ];
```

Comment: `var arr = [
  { "ID": 135, "Name": "Fargo Chan", "Address": "34, Baker Street" },
  { "ID": 432, "Name": "Aaron Luke", "Address": "BLDG 1, J Street" },
  { "ID": 252, "Name": "Dilip Singh", "Address": "Hotel J, SE" }
 ];
 
 var temp = arr[0];
 arr[0] = arr[1];
 arr[1] = temp;`

Comment: Another duplicate with a nicer solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306680/move-an-array-element-from-one-array-position-to-another

Comment: hi rory, here i need to swap array of json  but that you shared link as array values..