# How to place a specific record on the top of an arrayMap in Knockout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a very simple `arrayMap` in a `computed observable` like this:

```
self.Employees = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayMap(self.EmployeeData(),

      function(data) {

        return {

          Name: data.EmployeeName,
          value: data.EmployeeID
        }

      });

  })
```

The data is JSON:

```
[{"Name" : "John"}, {"EmployeeID" : "1w23"}]
```

Is there a way to have a specific Employee at the top of the list based on some condition? In a nutshell when I bind that data to en element a record is the first at the top?

Comment: *Is there a way to have a specific Employee at the top of the list based on some condition?* - Yes, but **what condition?** Just one record at the top or an order for the entire array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to reorder the `self.EmployeeData()` array, and put it at the top of the list, depending on the condition.

That's an easy JavaScript task. For an example, please, see this:

[Move an array element from one array position to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306680/move-an-array-element-from-one-array-position-to-another)

Or, if you don't mind using [lodash](https://lodash.com/), you can use a function like this:

```
var moveToStart = function(list, predicate) {
  var found = _.remove(list, predicate);
  list.unshift.apply(list, found);
};
```

As shown in this snippet:

```js
var list = [1,2,3,4,5];

var moveToStart = function(list, predicate) {
    var found = _.remove(list, predicate);
    list.unshift.apply(list, found);
};

$('#original').text(JSON.stringify(list));

moveToStart(list, function(e) { return e == 3;})
$('#moved3').text(JSON.stringify(list));

moveToStart(list, function(e) { return e%2 == 0;})
$('#movedEven').text(JSON.stringify(list));

moveToStart(list, function(e) { return e == 500;})
$('#moved500').text(JSON.stringify(list));


var list2 = [
 {name:'John', age: 41, },
 {name:'Frank', age: 23 },
 {name:'Anna', age: 37},
 {name:'Norah', age: 3}
];

$('#originalPeople').text(JSON.stringify(list2,null,2));

moveToStart(list2, function(p) { return p.age < 30});
$('#movedPeople').text(JSON.stringify(list2,null,2));
```

```css
p {
  font-family: Segoe, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}

pre {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Original:</p>
<pre id="original"></pre>
<p>After 3 to start:
  moveToStart(list, function(e) { return e == 3;})
<pre id="moved3"></pre>
<p>After even numbers to start: 
  moveToStart(list, function(e) { return e%2 == 0;})</p>
<pre id="movedEven"></pre>
<p>After non-existen number to start: 
  moveToStart(list, function(e) { return e == 500;})</p>
<pre id="moved500"></pre>
<br/>
<br/>
<p>Original list of persons<p>
<pre id="originalPeople"></pre>
<p>After moving younger than 30 to start<br/>
moveToStart(list2, function(p) { return p.age &lt; 30});
</p>
<pre id="movedPeople"></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, this is a great jump start!