# Javascript: moving elements in an array

Tags: javascript

```
var array = ["object1","object2","object3","object4","object5"];
var copy = array.slice();
copy.forEach(function(value) {
 if(value === "object3"){
  value = "newObject3"

 }
});

console.log(copy );
```

If i want to move `object3` in the array to the first index, after i assigned it a new value. How do I do it? and Whats the most effective and less time? any libraries like lodash can be used.

Comment: [array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is what you seek.

Comment: This subject is discussed quite well in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306680/move-an-array-element-from-one-array-position-to-another

Comment: And those aren't really objects, but strings ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5kdhtyt7/

Comment: thank you for the links!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array = ["object1", "object2", "object3", "object4", "object5"];
var copy = array.slice();
copy.forEach(function(value, index, theArray) {
  if (value === "object3") {
    theArray[index] = theArray[0];
    theArray[0] = "newObject3";
  }
});

console.log(copy);
```