# How do you put the last character 1st in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

The R is displaying last in the string initially it must display first how can I put the last character before the number value in the string so that it can display at the beginning of the value

[image]

```js
contentHtml += 
    "<td rowspan1=\"" + 1 + "\" class=\"" + (rowspan !== "" && rowspan > 1 ? "groups" : "") + " " + (!isNaN(value) || (!isNaN(value.toString().substr(1, value.length)) || value == "N/A" || value.length < 7 && value.toString().substr(value.length - 1) == '%') ? "text-center" : "text-left") + "\">" + value + (!isNaN(value) ? preFix : "") + color + (!isNaN(value) ? postFix : "") + "</td>";
if (rowspan > 1) {
    var rowspanContent = "<td rowspa1=\"" + rowspan + "\" class=\"" + (rowspan !== "" && rowspan > 1 ? "groups" : "") + " " + (!isNaN(value) || (!isNaN(value.toString().substr(1, value.length)) || value == "N/A" || value.length < 7 && value.toString().substr(value.length - 1) == '%') ? "text-center" : "text-left") + "\">" + value + (!isNaN(value) ? preFix : "") + color + (!isNaN(value) ? postFix : "") + "</td>";
}
```

Comment: code required..........! Post within the question.

Comment: Please use the search function in future: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306680/move-an-array-element-from-one-array-position-to-another

Comment: Is `postFix` set to `R`?

Comment: yes postfix is set to R

Comment: wha are ` rowspan1` and ` rowspa1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression and swap numbers and letters (not numbers).

```js
function swap(s) {
    var m = s.match(/^(\d+)(\D+)$/);
    return m[2] + m[1];
}

console.log(swap('1234R'));
```

Otherwise, you could change your code from

```
value + (!isNaN(value) ? preFix : "") + color + (!isNaN(value) ? postFix : "")
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

to

```
(!isNaN(value) ? preFix : "") + value + color + (!isNaN(value) ? postFix : "")
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and use `preFix` instead of `postFix`.

Comment: Thanx this is the correct answer + "" + (!isNaN(value) ? preFix : "") + value + (!isNaN(value) ? postFix : "") + color +

Answer (score 2):

If you want o swap the numbers and letters you should see Nina Scholz answer.

If you just want to put the last character first you can do it like this:

```
function lastToFirst(value){
   return value.slice(-1) + value.substring(0,value.length-1);
}
```

or even cleaner

```
function lastToFirst(value){
   return value.slice(-1) + value.slice(0,-1);
}
```

Comment: you could use `slice` for the number part as well: `return value.slice(-1) + value.slice(0, -1);`

Comment: Yup, you are right, that's even better!

Answer (score 1):

Direct answer is:

```
var value ="1234567R";
var res = "R" + value.split("R")[0];
alert(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Without code, it's compicated to help.
If just you want to put the last x chars to first, here is a little piece of code

```
var nb = 1;
var s = "123456789R";
var last = s.split(s[s.length - (nb - 1)])[1];
var s1 = s.slice(0, s.length - nb);
s = last + s1;
//s => "R123456789"
```