# Vue JS move item in list up and down array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have a vue js application which allows me to add items to an array.

After adding I'd like to add the ability against each item the ability to move the item up or down the array list.

I've tried the following but I don't think Vue.JS has the move method.

**My Vue method:**

```
changePos: function(item, type = 1) {
        this.items.move(this.items, item, type);
    },
```

**My template calling the method:**

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="(item, key) in items">
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-rounded" @click="changePos(item,1)">UP</button>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-rounded" @click="changePos(item,-1)">DOWN</button>
        </td>
        <td>@{{ item.code }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I get the following error:

> this.items.move is not a function

Comment: you need to have a method named `move()` in your `methods: {}`

Comment: Could you refer a link so I can research how to move an item up and down in an array using vue js?

Comment: You can find an implementation here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5306832/1696352

Comment: I think that your problem is that you are calling `this.items.move`, but the function move(), is referenced in your Vue instance, you should call: `this.move(this.items...)`

Answer (score 2):

## option 1: move all items up/down

```js
function up() {
    const tmp = array.shift()
    array.push(tmp)
}

function down() {
    const tmp = array.pop()
    array.unshift(tmp)
}
```

## option 2: use  `Array.map()`

```js
function up(index) {
    if (index === 0) { // if its the first in the array
        array.push(array.shift()) // same as option 1
    } else {
        array = array.map((element, i) => { // iterate array and change places
            if (i === index - 1) {
                return array[index];
            } else if (i === index) {
                return array[index - 1];
            } else {
                return element;
            }
        })
    }
}

function down(index) {
    if (index === array.length-1) { // if its the last in the array
        array.unshift(array.pop()) // same as option 1
    } else {
        array = array.map((element, i) => { // iterate array and change places
            if (i === index) {
                return array[index + 1];
            } else if (i === index + 1) {
                return array[index];
            } else {
                return element;
            }
        })
    }
}
```