# Sort an array of names except for one item

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Considering that I have an object like the following where it's possible to have many names and that 'The others' can appear at any index, how can I sort the array having 'The others' always as the first element and the rest of the names sorted in alphabetical order?

```
var friends = [
{ id: 1, name: 'Paul' },
{ id: 2, name: 'Mary' },
{ id: 3, name: 'The others' },
{ id: 4, name: 'John' }
];
```

For the sample array above, the desired result would be:

```
[
   { id: 3, name: 'The others' }, 
   { id: 4, name: 'John' }, 
   { id: 2, name: 'Mary' }, 
   { id: 1, name: 'Paul' }
]
```

Comment: check for `the others` as a value in the sort callback function, return appropriate value (-1 or 1) regardless of lexical order of the two elements being compared

Comment: I've changed the resulting array. Sorry for the confusion, but I need an array of sorted objects.

Comment: of course you do - the comment remains

Comment: So did you write a sort function that does the other half?

Comment: It's a little hard to pick the best answer for this one. Really good stuff on the answers.

Answer (score 5):

Simply check for either value in the sort callback being `The others` - return `-1` if `a` is that, or `1` if it's `b` - otherwise return the localeCompare of a and b

```
friends.sort(({name: a}, {name:b}) => a == "The others" ? -1 : (b == "The others" ? 1 : a.localeCompare(b)));
```

The "readable" and non-ES2015+ version of that

```
friends.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a.name == "The others") return -1;
  if (b.name == "The others") return 1;
  return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Sort like this:

```js
var friends = [
   { id: 1, name: 'Paul' },
   { id: 2, name: 'Mary' },
   { id: 3, name: 'The others' },
   { id: 4, name: 'John' }
];

friends.sort((a, b) => {
     if (a.name == "The others") {
         return -1; // a comes first
     } else if (b.name == "The others") {
         return 1;
     } else {
         return (a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1);
     }
 });

console.log(friends);
```

Answer (score 1):

Following are steps that you need to follow

1. Sort : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
2. Move : [Move an array element from one array position to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306680/move-an-array-element-from-one-array-position-to-another)

Please see following working example.

```js
var friends = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Paul'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Mary'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'The others'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'John'
  }
];

// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
friends.sort(function(a, b) {
  var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  if (nameA < nameB) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (nameA > nameB) {
    return 1;
  }

  // names must be equal
  return 0;
});

var indexOfTheOters = friends.reduce(function(acc, friend, index) {
  if(!acc && friend.name === 'The others') {
    acc = index;
  }
  return acc;
}, null);

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306680/move-an-array-element-from-one-array-position-to-another
Array.prototype.move = function (old_index, new_index) {
    if (new_index >= this.length) {
        var k = new_index - this.length;
        while ((k--) + 1) {
            this.push(undefined);
        }
    }
    this.splice(new_index, 0, this.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
    return this; // for testing purposes
};
friends.move(indexOfTheOters, 0)
console.log(friends);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
var friends = [
{ id: 1, name: 'Paul' },
{ id: 2, name: 'Mary' },
{ id: 3, name: 'The others' },
{ id: 4, name: 'John' }
];
var notConsidered = friends.filter(friend => friend.name == 'The others');
var friend = friends.filter(friend => friend.name!= 'The others');
var sortedfriend = friend.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
  else if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
  return 0;
});

sortedfriend.unshift(notConsidered[0])
console.log(sortedfriend);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. copy your (`The others` object) and store it into a variable using `filter`
2. remove it from the array using `filter`
3. sort the array by name property.
4. add the (`The others` object) in the beginning of your array using `unshift`

`compare` function copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1129270/6568620)

```js
var friends = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Paul'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Mary'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'The others'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'John'
    }
];


function compare(a,b) {
    if (a.name < b.name)
      return -1;
    if (a.name > b.name)
      return 1;
    return 0;
  }


// copy the others object
const theOthersObj = friends.filter(friend => friend.name === 'The others')[0];

const newFriends = friends
            .filter(friend => friend.name !== 'The others') // removing the others object
            .sort(compare) // storing the array by name
// Adding the others object in the first of the array
newFriends.unshift(theOthersObj);

console.log(newFriends);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to hard code your compare function so that 'The others' always has the lowest/greatest value.

```js
var friends = [
{ id: 1, name: 'Paul' },
{ id: 2, name: 'Mary' },
{ id: 3, name: 'The others' },
{ id: 4, name: 'John' }
];

function compare(a, b){
  if(a.name === "The others") {
   return -1;
  } else if (b.name === "The others") {
   return 1;
  } else if (a.name > b.name){
   return -1;
  } else if (a.name < b.name){
   return 1;
  } else {
   return 0;
  }
}

console.log(friends.sort(compare))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some great ideas here but what I found to be the simpler solutions are the two bellow:

Using sort:

```
friends.sort((a, b) => a.name !== b.name ? a.name < b.name ? -1 : 1 : 0).sort((a, b) => +(!b.name.localeCompare("The others")));
```

Using map and sort:

```
friends.map(o => o.name).sort((a,b) => a=="The others" ? -1 : b=="The others" ? 1 : a > b);
```