# How to delete and append element in JSON array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on an Ionic 3 project in which the response http data is in JSON array format like this (from the console): Country Array (5)

```
0: {record_id: "1", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "USA"}
1: {record_id: "2", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Japan"}
2: {record_id: "3", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Korea"}
3: {record_id: "4", local_TimeStamp: "15:00:00", country: "Thailand"}
4: {record_id: "5", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "China"}
```

How to (1) delete one of the above items (2) append to the last index of the above JSON array.  Note: Due to some special view requirements, step 1 and 2 need to be separate. So the result JSON array will look like this:

```
0: {record_id: "1", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "USA"}
1: {record_id: "2", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Japan"}
3: {record_id: "4", local_TimeStamp: "15:00:00", country: "Thailand"}
4: {record_id: "5", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "China"}
2: {record_id: "3", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Korea"}  <- Moved
```

I'd tried this code:

```
country.splice(country.findIndex(e => e.country === 'Korea'),1);
country = [...country];
// From console it's OK. Record deleted.
// Next append the element back:
country.push({record_id: "3", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Korea"});
country = [...country];
// From console looks OK. Element appended to the last index of the Json array.
```

But if I run the code again:

```
country.splice(country.findIndex(e => e.country === 'Korea'),1);
```

It can not find the element Korea anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move an array element from one array position to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306680/move-an-array-element-from-one-array-position-to-another)

Comment: If you delete it again why are you surprised not seeing it anymore ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're doing some unnecessary destructuring with the spread operator.  Here's a simple example using functions:

**Example**

```
let myCountries = [
  {record_id: "1", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "USA"},
  {record_id: "2", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Japan"},
  {record_id: "3", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Korea"},
  {record_id: "4", local_TimeStamp: "15:00:00", country: "Thailand"},
  {record_id: "5", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "China"}
];

function removeCountry(country, countries) {
  const index = countries.findIndex(c => c.country === country);
// Note: Country not found will mean index is -1
// which will remove the last country from the array.
  return countries.splice(index, 1);
}

function appendCountry(country, countries) {
  if (!country) return;

  countries.push(country);

  return countries;
}

// Usage:

const remove = removeCountry('Korea', myCountries);
appendCountry(remove);
```

**Update**
I've given an example of how to use this and save the removed country to a variable for easier appending.

Comment: This doesn't allow you to hold on to the target country in between the remove and the add.  Would that require separate work?

Comment: @ScottSauyet All that requires is a `return` of the splice result from `removeCountry`. I've updated my answer with an example usage.

Comment: That works.  A nice answer.  My answer is similar but treats the data as immutable.

Comment: Thank you all.  Unfortunately I'm still struggling on this as I do need to make the findIndex logic to work after delete (using findIndex) -> push back the same element (last position) -> delete again using findInex (failed). And I have to do it without same module functions.  The first deleted array will pass to a 3rd party sort function then it will pass back the result and I will append the record back.  And this process will repeat again and again.

Comment: Thank you Joshua Manns. Your code enlighten me solving the problems.

Answer (score 1):

you could do it like this:

```js
let country = [
    { record_id: "1", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "USA" },
    { record_id: "2", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Japan" },
    { record_id: "3", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Korea" },
    { record_id: "4", local_TimeStamp: "15:00:00", country: "Thailand" },
    { record_id: "5", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "China" }
];
const korea = country.splice(country.findIndex(e => e.country === 'Korea'), 1);
country = [...country, ...korea];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array.prototype.slice`, `array.prototype.find` and `spread`:

```js
var arr = [
    {record_id: "1", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "USA"},
    {record_id: "2", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Japan"},
    {record_id: "3", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Korea"},
    {record_id: "4", local_TimeStamp: "15:00:00", country: "Thailand"},
    {record_id: "5", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "China"}
];

var index = arr.findIndex(e => e.country === "Korea");    
var a = arr.slice(0, index);
var b = arr.slice(index + 1);
var c = arr.find(e => e.country === "Korea");

var result = [...a, ...b, c];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Renato Gama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91403/renato-gama)'s comment might do the trick for you. But *if* you need to do these steps separately:

> How to (1) delete one of the above items

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` to get an array without certain record, for example: `myArray.filter(record => record.country !== "Korea")`. But considering you want to add the record again, you could use `Array.prototype.splice`, like this:

```
var removed = myArray.splice(/* arguments */);
```

Above would be step 1 and step 2 would be pushing it again - `myArray.push(removed)`;

> But if I run the code again:
>
> country.splice(country.findIndex(e => e.country === 'Korea'),1);
>
> It can not find the element Korea anymore.

You can't find the element, since you removed it with `splice` and didn't save removed element to a variable.

Comment: I'm still having problem on this. Well, one thing I really don't understand is why the findIndex failed after push back the exact element.  The search suppose using the country value as the key.  Any idea?  I need this findIndex to work for my logic.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz Bubala. Your clear explanation helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do it, although the indices you supply in your expected output don't make sense to me:

```js
const originalCountries = [
  {record_id: "1", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "USA"},
  {record_id: "2", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Japan"},
  {record_id: "3", local_TimeStamp: "17:00:00", country: "Korea"},
  {record_id: "4", local_TimeStamp: "15:00:00", country: "Thailand"},
  {record_id: "5", local_TimeStamp: "16:00:00", country: "China"}
];

const removeCountry = (name, countries) => {
  const idx = countries.findIndex(c => c.country === name);
  return idx > -1 
      ? {
           countries: countries.slice(0, idx).concat(countries.slice(idx + 1)), 
           country: countries[idx]
        }
      : {countries, country: null};
};

const addCountry = (country, countries) => countries.concat(country);

console.log('Step 1');
const {countries, country} = removeCountry('Korea', originalCountries);
console.log(countries);

console.log('Step 2');
const updatedCountries = addCountry(country, countries);
console.log(updatedCountries);
```