# Move multiple array elements from one array position to another

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to move four items from an array of items to the first four positions.

Let say I have the below array:

```
var countryList=['Afghanistan','Albania', 'Argentina', 'Australia', 'Bangladesh', 'Belgium','Brazil',...]
```

I need to move Argentina, Australia, Belgium, and Brazil at first four positions. The modified array should look like:

```
var modifiedCountryList=['Argentina', 'Australia','Belgium', 'Brazil', 'Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Bangladesh', ...]
```

I have found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306680/move-an-array-element-from-one-array-position-to-another) but it is for a single array element position move.

It seems like simple but I can not wrap my head around it.

Comment: What have you tried? What logic is used to select those particular values? How are they ordered?

Comment: What are your inputs, if we solve this problem its going to be specific to your current input

Comment: @RobG and @ Lasitha Petthawadu - All the below answers are working for my particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new array with the output you expect. Also, I would suggest to use `indexOf` instead of `includes` as `includes` will give you error in IE browser. You can also make use of [*spread* syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `...` that will add the array elements to your new array.

```js
const countryList1 = ['Afghanistan','Albania', 'Argentina', 'Australia', 'Bangladesh', 'Belgium','Brazil'];
const countriesInFirst = ['Argentina', 'Australia','Belgium', 'Brazil'];

const countryList2 = [
  ...countriesInFirst,
  ...countryList1.filter(country => countriesInFirst.indexOf(country) === -1)
];
console.log(countryList2);
```

> `includes()` is not supported in IE browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Thank you, Ankit! your solution is working as expected

Answer (score 2):

You can `array#concat` both of your arrays. Using `Set` get the elements and place them in an array.

NOTE: Use of `Set` will remove the duplicate element, if any, in the result array.

```js
const countryList=['Afghanistan','Albania', 'Argentina', 'Australia', 'Bangladesh', 'Belgium','Brazil'],
    first = ['Argentina', 'Australia','Belgium', 'Brazil'],
    result = [...new Set([].concat(first, countryList))];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, @Hassan Imam! Your solution is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a new array with the desired countries in first and `.filter` out the matching elements in the first array:

```js
const countryList1 = ['Afghanistan','Albania', 'Argentina', 'Australia', 'Bangladesh', 'Belgium','Brazil'];
const countriesInFirst = ['Argentina', 'Australia','Belgium', 'Brazil'];

const countryList2 = [
  ...countriesInFirst,
  ...countryList1.filter(country => !countriesInFirst.includes(country))
];
console.log(countryList2);
```

Comment: Thank you CertainPerformance! Your solution is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var countryList=['Afghanistan','Albania', 'Argentina', 'Australia', 'Bangladesh', 'Belgium','Brazil'];

var filterArray = ["Argentina","Australia","Belgium","Brazil"];

var result = [...filterArray,...countryList].filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, Nishant Dixit! Your solution is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, exclude the first countries from the list of countries and then concatenate the filtered list to the first countries' list:

```js
const countries = ['Afghanistan','Albania', 'Argentina', 'Australia', 'Bangladesh', 'Belgium','Brazil'];
const first = ['Argentina', 'Australia','Belgium', 'Brazil'];

// Get the list of countries without first four countries
const filtered = countries.filter(country => !first.includes(country));

// Prepare the final list of countries
const c1 = first.concat(filtered);
console.log(c1);
```

Comment: Thank you 31piy! Your solution is working as expected.