# Move an item of an array to the front

Tags: javascript

I need to move a selected item in an array to the start of the array. Lets say I have an array of 5 items

```
[{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}].
```

Now, say I choose index 2 (which will be `C`) and I need to move `C` (index `2`) to the start of the Array. Finally the array should display as follows:

```
[{"C", "A", "B", "D", "E"}].
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift. While you're at it, read the doc of all the other methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move an array element from one array position to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306680/move-an-array-element-from-one-array-position-to-another)

Comment: this has nothing to do with Angular.

Comment: At least it would be great if someone can explain how this is done using `splice` than going ape ship downvoting ;/

Comment: @sharonHwk have you read the documentation of this method? What does it do? What does it return? Have you tried using it? What did you try, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** You can solve your problem by using nested `Array.Splice()` methods.  I would make this an extension method on arrays.

```
Array.prototype.move = function(from, to) {
    this.splice(to, 0, this.splice(from, 1)[0]);
};
```

**Explanation:** The inner `splice()` is essentially saying take the item you are wanting to move, remove it from the array, and use the value of that item in the outer `splice()`.  The outer `splice()` is saying to insert the item you just removed from the array at the index you specified in `to`.

`Array.prototype.move` is Javascript's way of creating an extension method called `move` on array objects.  Any code that has access to this function can call `move(from, to)` on any array (e.g. `myArray.move(2, 0)`).  So I would put this somewhere global so all your code can see it!

**Example:**

```
var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
letters.move(2, 0);
// letters is now ["C", "A", "B", "D", "E"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an example, how to do it:

```
<script>
  var people = [
          {name: 'Collin', city: 'Omaha', friend: false},
          {name: 'Alice', city: 'New York', friend: false},
          {name: 'Pasha', city: 'Moscow', friend: true},
          {name: 'Denis', city: 'St. Pete', friend: true}
  ];

  function toBeginning(index)
  {
    var obj = people[index];
    people.splice(index, 1);
    people.unshift(obj);
  } 

  // To test it
  alert(people[0].name); // Alert: Collin
  toBeginning(2);        // move position 2 (Pasha) to Beginning
  alert(people[0].name); // Alert: Pasha
```