# how to replace the position of the letter in a word using js?

Tags: javascript, string

lets take a word = **bird**
I want output =

**ibrd**

I should change its position to the beginning.
can I do this using JavaScript?
how can I do this using string.

Comment: Do this resolve it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306680/move-an-array-element-from-one-array-position-to-another

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem

```js
const changeLetter = (val /* string value */, index /* index of the letter (i in this scenario)*/) => {
  let temp = val.split('');

  temp.splice(index, 1);
  temp.unshift(val[index]);

  return temp.join('');
}

const val = 'bird';

console.log(changeLetter(val, 1));
```