# Return an ordered list of job details where the current logged in user is always displayed first

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, sorting

I have this array which I need help displaying, ordering the results based on whoever is the current logged in user. In this case it's Jane Doe, so the outcome will be her at the top. I heard `.reduce` can do this but i'm not sure on how to approach it. To find the current logged in user, I can get this from the global store.

```
const { user: id } = useStoreState(({ AccountModel }) => AccountModel);
console.log('id', id)
```

When I log this ^ I get "233334" which is Jane Doe's Id.

Currently comes back from the API response as:

```
const array = [
 {details: "", user: {id: "123456", name: "John Doe"} },
 {details: "", user: {id: "344333", name: "Bob Doe"} }
 {details: "", user: {id: "233334", name: "Jane Doe"} }
]
```

My job is to transform it into this in the frontend - React like this:

```
 const array = [
     {details: "", user: {id: "233334", name: "Jane Doe"} } // logged in user
     {details: "", user: {id: "123456", name: "John Doe"} },
     {details: "", user: {id: "344333", name: "Bob Doe"} }
    ]
```

Comment: when user get logged you will have to add new parameter to the `user` object. At the same time be aware that you working on local storage it's not a server

Comment: @x-magix I think you misunderstand the question.

Comment: you want Jane Doe to be first in list and than by this you find out that she is logged?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @x-magix I've updated my question content. So the logged in user will always be first. I need to do this in React.

Comment: if I understand correct than only what you want is changing position, than use this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306680/move-an-array-element-from-one-array-position-to-another