# How does ObservableCollection<T>.Move(int,int) work?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I can't seem to figure this one out by reading the [documentation for ObservableCollection.Move(int oldIndex, int newIndex) on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms654933.aspx):

> oldIndex Type: System.Int32 The zero-based index specifying the
>   location of the item to be moved. newIndex Type: System.Int32 The
>   zero-based index specifying the new location of the item.

I don't understand how it works. What happens to the item with `newIndex`? My assumption is that the index of each item with `index >= newIndex` is decremented. Is that assumption correct? And more importantly, is that behavior explained or described somewhere on MSDN?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Let me explain the behavior of `Move` in a form of a unit test:

```
[Test]
public void ObservableTest()
{
    var observable = new ObservableCollection<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" }; 

    observable.Move(1, 3); // oldIndex < newIndex 
    // Move "B" to "D"'s place: "C" and "D" are shifted left
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { "A", "C", "D", "B", "E" }, observable);

    observable.Move(3, 1); // oldIndex > newIndex 
    // Move "B" to "C"'s place: "C" and "D" are shifted right
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" }, observable);

    observable.Move(1, 1); // oldIndex = newIndex
    // Move "B" to "B"'s place: "nothing" happens
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" }, observable);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the second case, `Move(3, 1)`. Shouldn't it be A, D, B, C, E?

Comment: The observable collection is **mutable**. So in my example the initial state before calling `Move(3, 1)` is `"A", "C", "D", "B", "E"` .

Answer (score 4):

I would go for the simple explanation:

The object is moved to the position indicated, and then all objects in collection are re-indexed from zero and up.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being voted up. The two other answers clearly show that the _correct_ simple explanation is that the item is removed, and then inserted back.

Comment: It is obvious that the item is removed and inserted back, that doesn't need a complex demonstration/unit testing. The author was asking about the indexes. My answer, although not the chosen one, targets that aspect.

Comment: I think the only thing that really explains it well is Ludo's comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10471323/897609) of [@nemesv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/872395/nemesv) what helps me to remember the behavior is that `myObservableCollection.Move(oldIndex, newIndex)` is equivalent of:

```
var movedItem = myObservableCollection[oldIndex];
myObservableCollection.RemoveAt(oldIndex);
myObservableCollection.Insert(newIndex, movedItem);
```