# Find index of number if item exists in ObservableCollection in C#/WPF

Tags: c#

In the following code I'm checking if a certain item exists in an `ObservableCollection` and if it does, I want to grab its index so I can move that item to the top but I cannot figure it out.

My object:

```
public class RecentFile
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string DateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

Cod for finding index of item:

```
if (recentFilesObservableCollection.Any(f => f.FileName == "MyFileName")) {

    foreach (RecentFile file in recentFilesObservableCollection) {
        if (file.FileName == "MyFileName") {
            var x = RecentFilesDataGrid[(recentFilesObservableCollection.IndexOf(file)];
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to get the index number if the item exists?

Ultimately what I need to do is...

1. Check if item exists
2. If it does move it to the top of the list

Comment: `var index = 0;` outside of the `foreach`. `index++` at the end of (inside) the `foreach`. Or consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471588/how-to-get-index-using-linq .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does ObservableCollection<T>.Move(int,int) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471222/how-does-observablecollectiont-moveint-int-work)

Comment: Did you try `var index = 0;
            foreach (RecentFile file in recentFilesObservableCollection) {

                if (file.FileName == "MyFileName") {
                    recentFilesObservableCollection.Move(index, 0); break;
                }
                index++;
            }
`? Note that `Any` is not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if item exists. If it does get the item to find its index. From there move it.

```
//Check if item exists
if (recentFilesObservableCollection.Any(f => f.FileName == "MyFileName")) {
    //If it does, get item
    var file = recentFilesObservableCollection.First(f => f.FileName == "MyFileName");
    //grab its index
    var index = recentFilesObservableCollection.IndexOf(file);
    if (index > 0)
        //move it to the top of the list
        recentFilesObservableCollection.Move(index, 0);
}
```

Another alternative that achieves the same result with less enumerations.

```
var item = recentFilesObservableCollection
    .Select((file, index) => new { file, index })
    .FirstOrDefault(f => f.file.FileName == "MyFileName"));
if(item != null && item.index > 0) // or if(item?.index > 0)
    recentFilesObservableCollection.Move(item.index, 0);
```

Comment: @ Nkosi - It did the trick thanks. Quick question, is there a way to ignore case when checking if file exists? Right now if I check for `"MyFileName"` and `"myFileName"` exists, it returns false.

Comment: @fs_tigre use `string.Equals(f.file.FileName, "MyFileName", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` to compare them ignoring case.

Comment: Hmm, I'm a little confused with `f.file.FileName` I'm not sure what `file` is, I get an error saying that it doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: @fs_tigre I though you were referring to the second example. Just replace that with what was used in the first example

Comment: Oh, sorry I'm using the code from your first example.

Comment: FYI - With the second example I had to delete `&& item.index > 0` from the `IF` statement otherwise I would get a crash when `MyFileName` was matched and it was the first item in the collection. After this little adjustment, everything worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Int index=YourCollection.IndexOf(x => x.fileName == “name”);
And then use MoveItem which takes current index and destination index.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no inbuilt `FindIndex` method available. I guess you meant `IndexOf`.

Comment: I did you can also find it at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx under methods

Comment: This code does not compile, `ObservableCollection<T>.IndexOf(...)` expects a parameter of type `T` as an input, not a lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can create extension methods similar to `List<T>.FindIndex(...)` methods:

```cs
public static class ObservableCollectionExtensions
{
    public static int FindIndex<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> ts, Predicate<T> match)
    {
        return ts.FindIndex(0, ts.Count, match);
    }

    public static int FindIndex<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> ts, int startIndex, Predicate<T> match)
    {
        return ts.FindIndex(startIndex, ts.Count, match);
    }

    public static int FindIndex<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> ts, int startIndex, int count, Predicate<T> match)
    {
        if (startIndex < 0) startIndex = 0;
        if (count > ts.Count) count = ts.Count;

        for (int i = startIndex; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (match(ts[i])) return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int index = recentFilesObservableCollection.FindIndex(f => f.FileName == "MyFileName");
if (index > 0)
{
    // Move it to the top of the list
    recentFilesObservableCollection.Move(index, 0);
}
```