# Moving items up and/or down in a List or LinkedList

Tags: c#, list, datagrid, linked-list

I've currently got a `DataGrid` which is bound to a `List`. This `List` is populated through a database query. Now, I'd like to be able to select an item in the `DataGrid`, and move it up or down, and at the same time having it move in the `List`.

I thought about `LinkedLists`, because I also need to have the ability of inserting above or below specific spots in the list. However, I've only ever heard of `LinkedLists` and I'm not even sure where to start. Looking at the MSDN for it, there doesn't seem to be a built in `MoveUp()`/`MoveDown()` methods. I figure, if I can move it in the list, then getting it to move in the `DataGrid` will be simple.

My question is: Is there a way to move items up and down in a `LinkedList` or `List`?

Answer (score 0):

To move an item in a list, you'll have to remove it and then re-insert it at the desired location:

[Generic List - moving an item within the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450233/generic-list-moving-an-item-within-the-list)