# LinkedList moving a value to another position java

Tags: java

I have a LinkedList like this

```
 LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
    l.add("1");
    l.add("2");
    l.add("3");
    l.add("4");
    l.add("5");
    l.add("6");
```

i want move the value 6 to before 3 and also deleted in the old position.

I need a command like this l.move(5 to 3) or l.shift(5 to 3).

I can manually do like

```
String s = l.get(5);
l.add(2,s);
l.remove(6);
```

Thanks

Comment: Be careful: with `get(5)`, you're getting the entry at index 5, not the entry that value is 5 (as I believe you were expecting). Same for the other methods of List you're using.

Comment: Don't use [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450233/generic-list-moving-an-item-within-the-list ?

Answer (score 0):

There are no built-in java methods to do what you are asking for in the `LinkedList` class, so you will have to define your own method, or create a class that extends `LinkedList` and add this functionality to that class.