# moving an item within the generic list based on timezone

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, observablecollection

I have below-mentioned list foo which contains the volume data for **Pacific daylight time**, If I want to see the volume in **mountain standard time** I am trying to move the list items based on the difference of time between 2 time zones

Let's say the difference is 3 hours I expect the result to be

```
B1Volume = B4Volume;
B2Volume = B5Volume;
...................
B21Volume = B24Volume;

var foo = new List<XYZ>();

public class XYZ
{
    public String TimeZone { get; set; }
    public Decimal? B1Volume { get; set; }
    public Decimal? B2Volume { get; set; }
    public Decimal? B3Volume { get; set; }
    public Decimal? B4Volume { get; set; }
    public Decimal? B5Volume { get; set; }
    // .............
    // .............
    public Decimal? B24Volume { get; set; }
}
```

Am trying to follow [Generic List - moving an item within the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450233/generic-list-moving-an-item-within-the-list)

Comment: In your example (increase by 3), what would be the values of B22 - B24?

Comment: It appears this question has nothing to do with moving list items, but rather adjusting property values of class instances based on some other value.

Comment: @Rufus L  B22Volume = B1Volume

Comment: @RufusL Thanks for the reply , how do I adjust property values of class instances based on the while ? Please provide example

Comment: Is it possible to store the volumes in a `List<decimal?> Volumes` property instead of individually named properties? That would make it pretty easy.

Comment: @RufusL class xyz has more than 50 properties with different data types , Even I agree if it was List<decimal> that would have made easy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157950/discussion-between-mahesh-and-rufus-l).