# How to move a subset of items in a list in c#?

Tags: c#, list

I have the following list:

```
List<string> l=new List<string()>{"a","b","c","d","1","2","3","4","a1","b2","c3","d4"};
```

And I have `oldIndex`,`size` and `newIndex`.

Let's say for the above list `oldIndex = 4`,`size = 4`,`newIndex = 0`.

The output list I would like is:

```
{"1","2","3","4","a","b","c","d","a1","b2","c3","d4"};
```

The solution I've found is(which is not working for all cases):

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    if(oldIndex<newIndex)
    {
        var x=l[oldIndex];
        l.RemoveAt(oldIndex);
        l.Insert(newIndex+size-1,x);
    }
    else
    {
        var x=l[oldIndex+i];
        l.RemoveAt(oldIndex+i);
        l.Insert(newIndex+i,x);
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to this, perhaps using LINQ or something better, or is the above the only way to this?

I found the above answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450233/generic-list-moving-an-item-within-the-list) link. The difference in this question is that I would like to move a block, and not just single element.

Comment: Check `AddRange()` and `RemoveRange()` methods of `List<T>`.

Comment: I think you can try using InsertRange.

Comment: What is the expected result if I call your code with `var size = 2;
            var oldIndex = 3;
            var newIndex = 6;`?

Comment: {"a","b","c","2","3","4","d","1","a1","b2","c3","d4"}; this was the output if I take `var size = 2; var oldIndex = 3; var newIndex = 6;` (my mistake)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following for this:

```
List<string> removedRange = l.GetRange(oldIndex, size);
l.RemoveRange(oldIndex, size);
l.InsertRange(newIndex, removedRange);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to do this.

[Raviraj Palvankar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49043891/336648) is probably the simplest, but to complement it (and since you specifically mentioned linq), here are a couple of (*admittedly somewhat over-engineered*) alternatives.

```
List<string> l = new List<string>{"a","b","c","d","1","2","3","4","a1","b2","c3","d4"};

var oldIndex = 4;
var size= 4;
var newIndex = 0;
```

To move:

```
var toMove = l.Skip(oldIndex).Take(size).ToList();
var newList = l.Take(oldIndex).ToList().Concat(l.Skip(oldIndex + size)).ToList();

newList.InsertRange(newIndex, toMove);
```

If you're able to move the section `{"a","b","c","d"}` instead (requires knowing a different new index, and does not require `oldIndex`, since it will be 0), then the move-operation itself becomes easier:

```
var newIndex = 4; // Replace previous value which was 0
var size= 4; // Elements a - d

var newList = l.Skip(size).ToList();
newList.InsertRange(newIndex, l.Take(size));
```

...and yet another way (which may actually be the simplest to *read*):

```
var oldIndex = 4;
var size= 4;

var toMove = l.Skip(oldIndex).Take(size).ToList();
var firstPart = l.Take(oldIndex);
var lastPart = l.Skip(oldIndex + size);
var combined = toMove.Concat(firstPart).Concat(lastPart);
```